# Printing ascending ASCII, Cops

Tags: cops-and-robbers

This is the cops' thread. The robbers' thread [goes here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/67757/printing-ascending-ascii-robbers).

Write a program or function consisting only of **printable ASCII characters** (that excludes tab and newline) that outputs at least 5 printable ASCII characters in ascending order (from space to tilde / 32 to 126). Characters can be outputted several times, as long as they are adjacent to each other. A single trailing newline is accepted. You must provide the full output, and for every 6 characters in your code you must provide one character in your code, at the position it appears. If your code has 5 or less characters, then you have to reveal only the length. You shall not reveal more than 1 character per 6 in your code.

So if your code `alphaprinter` outputs the alphabet from a-z, then you need to reveal 2 characters of your code (use underscore for the others), for instance:

```
al__________  // or
__p__p______  // or
__________er
```

Rules / specifications:

- You cannot append trailing white spaces that doesn't have a function.
- You can not use comments (but the robbers can use comments when cracking the code)
- Built-in cryptographic primitives (includes any rng, encryption, decryption, and hash) aren't allowed.
- In languages where the **default** output are like in MATLAB: `ans =`, then that's accepted, as long as it's **clearly stated** and shown that `ans =` is outputted. It should also be clearly stated whether this is part of the "ascending output" or not.
- The output must be deterministic
- Using a non-free language [is not accepted](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default/7212#7212)
- The output doesn't have to be consecutive characters. Both `abcde` and `abcdg` are valid outputs.
- The characters do not need to be distinct as long as the output contains at least 5 characters. `aaaaa` and `aaacc` are valid.
- Answers that assumes a REPL environment are not considered to be valid programs or functions and are therefore not allowed.
- STDERR is not considered valid output, but data may written to STDERR.

If the revealed characters are underscores, then you must identify it as shown below. 
In this case, the second and sixth character are revealed underscores, while the others are unknown.

```
_____________
 |   |
```

**Note:** The robbers only need to find a code that produces the same output. The language, the length of the robbers solution, and the position of the revealed characters must also match.

Your score is the number of characters in your code. The winner will be the submission with the lowest score that hasn't been cracked in 7 days. 
Only submissions that are posted in 2015 (UTC) are eligible for the win. Submissions that are posted later than this are welcome, but can not win.

In order to claim the win you need to reveal the full code (after 7 days).

Your post should be formatted like this (nn is the number of characters):

---

## Language, nn characters

Output:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Code (12 characters):

```
al__________
```

---

If the code is cracked, insert [Cracked](link to cracker) in the header.
If the submission is safe, insert "Safe" in the header and reveal the full code in your answer. Only answers that have revealed the full code will be eligible for the win.

Comment: Does this mean that if my code is `print ( "abcde" )`, I can reveal three whitespaces?

Comment: @Adnan, technically yes, you can.

Comment: When somebody makes a seed answer, we might not even know the length of the code.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Seed isn't allowed

Comment: @Adnan I suppose it doesn't require any brainpower, only brute-force power.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 yes, and RNGs are not allowed

Comment: What's the tie breaker for the cops?

Comment: @Martin I think it will be number of votes followed by submission date/time if the votes are equal.

Comment: I just had the same idea as @Adnan and that seems really unfriendly to the robbers :/

Comment: Can I return the text rather than printing it?

Comment: @RikerW it's not enough to return the text. See cat's comment on your answer.

Comment: I saw it, I just needed verification.  But okay.

Comment: Can I stipulate there are no comments in my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### [Hexagony](https://github.com/mbuettner/hexagony), 8 characters, safe

```
_______.
```

prints

```
123456
```

You can [try Hexagony online](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/)

#### Solution

```
`&)!."@.
```

The `` ` `` is just misdirection to make the code look like it requires side-length 3. Unless the interpreter is executed with `-d` the backtick is simply stripped from the source code before determining the layout. Afterwards, the code fits into side-length 2:

```
 & )
! . "
 @ .
```

This moves the memory pointer (MP) around one hexagon of the memory grid, while copying the value to the next edge, incrementing it and printing it.

This is what the memory grid looks like, with the MP starting the marked position:

[image]

Initially all edges are zero. The first `&` is a no-op, but `)` increments the edge and `!` prints the `1`. Then `"` moves back to the left (the edge labelled *2*). There, `&` copies a value. Since the edge is currently zero, the left neighbour (in the direction of the MP) will be copied which is the `1` we just printed. `)` increments it, `!` prints the `2`. This continues as long as we're visiting new edges and we print all digits up to `6`. When we hit the edge we started on, `&` will copy the *right* neighbour instead (because the edge value is positive), so the edge becomes `0` again, and control flow jumps to the last row, where `@` terminates the program.

[Try it online.](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=YCYpIS4iQC4&input=)

Comment: I got `123456`, but it only doesn't stop running and needs to be killed. Is that allowed?

Comment: @Adnan I don't think it is. My program terminates.

Answer (score 13):

### Perl, 46 characters (safe)

Output:

````
((()))*++,---../00011123445556667779::;;<<==??@@AAACEFGHHHIKKMMNOOOPPQQQRRSSSVWXXYY[[[\]]]^^^```aaeeffggghjjjnpppqqrttuwxxyzz{{{
````

Code:

```
print _______________________________________;
```

I somehow managed to delete the original in the space of a week, but I think this is right:

> `print chr()x(($i=($i*41+7)%97)&3)for(40..123);`

Comment: Well done. You turned it into a mystery string printer. ಠ_ಠ +1

Comment: watch it include some homebrew random number generator :P

Comment: I strongly suspect the output is sorted characters from a short list of error messages from eval'ing something.

Answer (score 11):

## Brainfuck, 48 characters, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67823/34388) by Mitch Schwartz

I made this one for the robbers. It is definitely not going to be the winning submission :)

```
____[_____[_______]__]___[___________]___[_____]
```

This outputs:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

**Solution:**

> `++++[>++++[>++++<-]<-]+++[>++++++++<-]>++[>+.<-]`

I tested it [here](https://copy.sh/brainfuck/).

**Hint:** Don't try to find programs generated by online generators haha. This was handwritten and can only be solved by logical thinking :)

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67823/2537).

Answer (score 7):

### [Noisy 3SP](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Three_Star_Programmer#Variants), 89 characters (safe)

```
0 _____________________________ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ __2_2__________________________________
```

Original program:

```
0 0 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 3 2 2 2 2 0 3 0 1
```

This program prints

```
 !"#$$
```

(note the leading space), and *nothing else!*

Explanation (*n refers to the nth cell in memory):

```
0 0 0                                Increment *0 to 3 (via the 0s in *0, *1, and *2)
2 (32 times)                         Increment *3 to 32 (via the 0 in *2 and the 3 in *0)
                                      (Note that *3 mod 256 is the character that prints)
0                                    Increment *32 (via the 3 in *0 and the 32 in *3)
3                                    Increment *1 (via the 32 in *3 and the 1 in *32)
                                      (Note that printing is on when *1 mod 2 is 1,
                                       which means " " prints right here)
2 (4 times)                          Increment *3 to 36 (printing '!"#$')
0                                    Increment *36 (via *3) (printing "$" again)
3                                    Increment *1 to 2 (via *36) (printing turns off)
0                                    Increment *36 to 2 (via *3)
1                                    Increment *0 to 4 (via *2)
```

The last two commands turn out to be sufficient to prevent 1 from ever being incremented again on subsequent passes through the program, which means nothing is ever again printed, though it will go on setting all memory addresses from *36 onward to the value 36 forever.

Comment: `an esolang in which structured programming is impossible and every program has to be written from scratch.` 0_0 plus one from me.

Comment: Don't be intimidated. It does go on to say `This is probably not that language`. If you sit down and try to write a program that gives that output, you'll probably get something very similar.

Comment: Thanks, but no thanks ^_^ the specs made me lose my mind. It's like brainf*** all over again, except worse,

Comment: Looking forward to seeing your program revealed. I can't think of a way to modify my answer so that I get 2's in those places instead of 5's. You've bested me! Cool language :)

Comment: Aww...always sad to see someone give up :/

Comment: Aaah, nice use of *32 for starting the print. I got too stuck on using the low end registers and setting everything up early. I think it was the fact that our programs were the same length that threw me off. Your program would have been 85 chars if you had terminated it. Congrats on making it safe!

Answer (score 7):

### CJam, 13 characters

```
_____________
  ||
```

prints

```
7LLMYahnsuv
```

You can [try CJam online.](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/)

#### Solution

```
{`__Jf^er$}_~
```

I thought basing a cop on a generalised quine was pretty clever and novel. The moment I posted this, I realised that `__` and `er` are completely useless, which is why I posted the 8-byte CJam cop for a more competitive score. Pietu cracked that one rather quickly, so I was afraid he'd figure out this one as well. I suppose the unnecessarily convoluted character transliteration saved it.

Anyway, the code takes its own characters (except the `_~`), XORs each one with 19 for obfuscation and then sorts them.

This cop led me to the "discovery" of [xorting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/68109/8478), although I'm not actually using it here (and it would probably be near impossible to make use of it with a short generalised quine).

Answer (score 6):

## <s>Matlab</s> Octave, 27 characters, safe

#### Challenge

Regarding the new language restrictions: It also works in Octave.

```
____________3_3___4_3______
```

Output (in Octave): (`ans =` is not part of the output, the first character of the output is `"`)

```
ans = """""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""########$$$$$$%%%%&&&&'''(()))**++,,-../001223456789:;<=>?@BCDFGHJKMNPRTUWY[]_acehjloq
```

Output (in Matlab): (`ans = \n\n` is not part of the output, the output is just the last line)

```
ans =

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""########$$$$$$%%%%&&&&'''(()))**++,,-../001223456789:;<=>?@BCDFGHJKMNPRTUWY[]_acehjloq
```

#### Solution

> `[fix((0:.07/3:3).^4+34),'']`
>
>
>   We are basically looking at this function, converted to ASCII values.
>  [image]

Comment: Could this be the floored y-values of a quintic?

Comment: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7212/8478

Comment: @LegionMammal978 I do not understand what you mean, but because you are asking I think it might very well be=)

Comment: @MartinBüttner I was not aware of this recent restriction, should perhaps be pointed added to the question.

Comment: +1 for `It also works in Octave.`

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), 60 characters, [Cracked by user81655](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67815/41859)

Not promising to win, but hopefully fun to crack:

```
e_e_______a__a____e___e________e__o___________o______o______
```

This is a function that returns:

```
    :ERacddeeeeeeffiinnnoorrrrst
^^^^ -> 4 whitespaces
```

---

**Edit**

[user81655 cracked it](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67815/41859) character by character:

> ``` e=e=>{try{a}catch(e){return[...e.toString()].sort().join``}} ```

Answer (score 4):

## Fortran, 45 characters, safe

Complete Output:

```
 !"$)0<Ka|
```

Cat [attempted to cracked it here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67822/46231)

Code (45 characters):

```
pr_gr_m____________________/___3____________
```

Program code:

> `program t;print*,(char(i**3/8+33),i=1,9);end`

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67822/46231)

Comment: @Cat No, not cracked. Incorrect output: there is no trailing `/`!

Comment: Evidently, I am blind, sorry.

Comment: This is quite a challenge. (Well, I don't know Fortran, but it's a fairly easy language to get the hang of)

Comment: @cat I'm glad you like it ;-)

Comment: A few of the SO answers I've found while trying to crack this were answered by you :)

Comment: I give up; I've tried everything from variables to concatenation to a do/end loop. Nice submission!

Comment: It's "program" something

Comment: @cat I posted the program code...

Comment: `$ gfortran test.f
test.f:1:1:

 program a;print*,(char(i**3/8+33),i=1,9);end
 1
Error: Non-numeric character in statement label at (1)
test.f:1:1:

 program a;print*,(char(i**3/8+33),i=1,9);end
 1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
`

Comment: It's Fortran 90... You need to call the file test.f90.

Comment: I think you should have specified a certain compiler in your post because obviously, the one you used isn't gfortran, the most common one.

Comment: I used `gfortran`! And I specified the Standard (Fortran 95) - you complained about that one ;-)

Comment: Why does a two character difference in the filename make it uncompilable? You say in the post `Fortran 95+` yet this only compiles with a certain filename?

Comment: Because `gfortran` will interpret `*.f` files as fixed-format (~FORTRAN 77) code. This is a usual convention, similar to .c/.cpp.

Comment: I would like to point out that `gfortran --help` doesn't mention anything of this sort.

Comment: `man gfortran` does. See the section below `-ffree-form` and `-ffixed-form`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jolf](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Jolf/), 27 characters, [Cracked by Adnan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67881/31957)

```
________W___________--_____
                         |
```

prints

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrst
```

[Interpreter](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/).

Original code:

```
on*2toHEWn)oH+H `pl$--$n}_H
on                          set n
  *2t                        to twenty
     oHE                    set H to the empty string
        Wn)                 while(n){
           oH+H             append to H
                `pl$--$n     get the nth character of the alphabet, decrement n before
                        }   }
                         _H print H reversed
```

Congrats to Adnan! You scare me.

---

Here, you can test your submission, to see how many characters must be removed.

```js
setInterval(function(){r=document.querySelector("textarea").value;document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=r.length/6-r.split("").filter(function(x){return x=="_"}).length|0},20)
```

```css
*{font-family:Consolas,monospace}textarea{width:100%;resize:none;height:auto;min-height:1.2em;}b{color:red;}
```

```html
<textarea>Example Program</textarea><div>You must reveal <b id="output">n</b> characters.</div>
```

Comment: http://cdn.meme.am/instances2/500x/3556122.jpg

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67881/34388)

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, 46 characters, safe

Source:

```
for(_______________________=________________);
```

Outputs a 84 characters long string:

```
!!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789::;<=>?@AABCDEEFGHIIJKLLMNNOPPQRRSTTUUVWWXXYYZZ[[\\]]^^__`
```

**Hint**

> What'd you say? My cousine is involved?

**Revealed code**

> This method is relatively simply as it prints up to *64* characters starting at `chr(32)`. The obscuring part is, that the iterator `i` is not incremented linearly. It's incremented by it's own *cosine* value which will result in repeated and missing characters.
>  `for(;$i<64;)echo chr(32+$i+=cos(deg2rad($i)));`
>  `for(_______________________=________________);`

Answer (score 4):

## R, 60 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67911/6741) by plannapus

Output:

```
0123456789ABCDEFGHTUVWXYZdefghijklmnopqrstuvw
```

Code:

```
___(_(_:_____________]_____________6]_______s_4_____,___=___
```

I think this will not be so hard. We will see.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67911/6741)

Comment: @plannapus Good job! :)

Answer (score 4):

### Python 3.4, 127 characters - SAFE

This is my first coppers-post. I think/hope it's not too hard or too obvious.

The obfuscated code:

```
_______inspect__________________getsource_____________________________________________print__________c*s_______________________
```

creates this output (there are 5 spaces at the beginning; total length is 7740 characters):

```
     """"""""""""(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((()))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))**********************...................................................................................................................;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;==============================[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiijjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnoooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooopppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppprrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

### Edit 25 sept 2021, the answer in [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/)

```python
import inspect;s=sorted(inspect.getsource(inspect.getmodule(inspect.currentframe())));print("".join([c*s.index(c) for c in s]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc0xDsIwDIXhq0SdEoYsjFVPghiQ41IjYke2I8HpQwYkeNv/La@9/RA@j0G1iXogtobgq202E0v8Qr6jm3QF/JcqpT9/Al0V2Xe9VYxpbm1K7HFZ8kOI4wVOlokLviKksIsGmIfBrimN8QE)

The code gets the code itself as a string and then repeaths every i-th character i times. Finally the resulting string is sorted.

Funny thing is thus that all the characters of the solution are in the output! ;-)

Comment: You are already safe.

Comment: @nrgmsbki4spot1 : thanks for pointing that out. Luckily I found the code I made almost 6 years ago. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 13 characters, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68072/34388) by quintopia

I'm an idiot. I forgot to implement power function (-_-｡). Here is the obfuscated code:

```
__D____<_____
```

My original code was:

```
99DF2}r<F*}bR
```

Explanation:

```
99DF2}r<F*}bR

99            # Pushes 99
  D           # Duplicates the top item
   F }        # Creates a for loop: For N in range(0, 99)
    2         # Pushes 2 (this will be done 99 times)
      r       # Reverses the stack
       <      # Decrement on the last item
        F }   # Creates a for loop: For N in range(0, 98)
         *    # Multiplies the last two item of the stack, which now looks like
              # [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, ...]. Basically we're calculating 2^99
           b  # Converts the last item to binary
            R # Reverses the last item of the stack
```

This will output:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
```

Yes, that is 99 zeroes followed by a 1.

---

**Note**, I have a power function implemented right now. So this could be done in six bytes:

```
Y99mbR
```

Comment: Is it pronounced like "Osabie"?

Comment: @cat Some say "Osabie", others say "Usable", they're all correct haha :)

Comment: @Adnan Sorry, you forgot me. I say it like "three hundred seventy-one thousand, four hundred eighty-six" ;)

Comment: String times number doesn't work as string repetition. :(

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Hehehe :) (that's for cases when the string itself is also a number, e.g. `"4"3*` = 12)

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68072/47050)

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 17 characters, [cracked by Pietu1998](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/67757/printing-ascending-ascii-robbers/68124#68124)

Output:

```
""''''''''''''''''''''0000000000111111111122222222223333333333XXXXXXXXXX[[[[[[]]]]]]
```

Code:

```
___________#____1
```

My solution:

```
Sjkm^dT%"'%#X"291
```

Pietu1998's solution:

```
S`u]G6*T`t"#X0231
```

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68124/30164)

Comment: I really like your code. I was thinking about hexadecimal for some time when cracking this, but I didn't know enough about Python's string formatting to get the same code. (Particularly, the `#` alternate form was new to me.)

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 8 characters, safe

*Stable version of the compiler working in Octave hopefully coming soon. Meanwhile, this [GitHub commit works](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/tree/77a5eba228ccedec8ac0d58d0f1842aba03858cc), and in particular runs the original code that produces the indicated output*

*This submission counts as posted on December 28, 2015, 15:30 UTC*

Output:

```
$**0016688??@HHQ
```

Code (8 characters):

```
_:______
```

#### Solution

```
6:9tX*Sc
```

What it does:

```
6:9          % numeric vector [6 7 8 9]
t            % duplicate
X*           % Kronecker tensor product
S            % sort in ascending order 
c            % convert to char. Implicit display
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is legitimate, since MATL seems to require Matlab to be interpreted. (http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7212/8478)

Comment: As @MartinBüttner pointed out, this language is ineligible for Cops and Robbers due to the paywall.

Comment: @cat I suppose the question is whether the interpreter works in Octave.

Comment: @MartinBüttner, I've looked through most of the source code in the compiler and I can't find anything that shouldn't run in Octave, but I may have missed something. I don't have Octave on my laptop. Luis must confirm, but I'm quite sure the interpreter should run in Octave.

Comment: I didn't know about that restriction in Cops and Robbers (but it totally makes sense). I haven't tested the compiler in Octave. It may work, but it probably needs some tweaking first. I'll add a disclaimer in my answer saying it's not eligible for winning @MartinBüttner

Comment: While I prepare a stable version of the compiler for Octave, this [GitHub commit works](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/tree/77a5eba228ccedec8ac0d58d0f1842aba03858cc), where "works" means it compiles and runs all examples I've tried, and in particular runs the original code that produces the output indicated here. Does this qualify now, or is it too late? @MartinBüttner

Comment: @LuisMendo well, normally interpreter changes after the challenge are disallowed, but since this doesn't actually affect how the language works, making an exception might be fine. Ultimately, it's Stewie's call. But I think at the very least the deadline for cracking this should be extended.

Comment: Yes, it should count as newly posted. What do you think, @StewieGriffin?

Comment: @Luis i agree. It can be counted as newly posted. :-)

Comment: @StewieGriffin Great! I've updated the answer to include that

Comment: Well I guess we're tied for the win now. It's Stewie's call which of your two timestamps counts for the tie breaker, I suppose. ;)

Comment: @MartinBüttner Nah, your answer has more votes, and definitely involved more work. That Hexagony language of yours sounds impressive!

Comment: @LuisMendo, I'm sorry to say Martin's answer won, based on number of votes. Great answer though =)

Comment: @StewieGriffin Thanks! I'd have picked his too :-)

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica 10.1, 98 characters, safe

Output is [here](http://pastebin.com/8PNpkHcD). The entire output has 838,316 characters and a trailing newline.

Code:

```
Print[""<>Chara__________________________________________________________________________________]
```

Yes, this must be run in 10.1. <sub>*(hint)*</sub> The original program:

```
Print[""<>Characters@ToCamelCase@ExampleData@{"Text","DonQuixoteIEnglish"}~SortBy~ToCharacterCode]
```

Comment: At first I was quizzical as to which ASCII standard contains a hundred thousand codepoints, but now I understand,

Comment: Since when is Mathematica free?

Comment: @mbomb007 You would have to ask Martin Buettner.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 no need to. You can use the [Wolfram Cloud](http://www.wolframcloud.com/).

Answer (score 3):

### CJam, 8 bytes, [Cracked by Pietu1998](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67917/8478)

```
__:_____
```

prints

```
%*;a|~
```

You can [try CJam online](http://cjam.tryitonline.net).

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67917/30164)

Answer (score 3):

## Malbolge, 254 characters, [cracked by Adnan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/67757/printing-ascending-ascii-robbers/68219#68219)

Code:

```
_____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ __
```

Output:

```
`AB\cd`
```

I kinda cheated by putting a space for every 6th character. Oh well...

---

Adnan's cracked code:

```
('&%: ^"!65 4Xzyx w4-Qs rpo'K mlk"' ~Dfdc ba}v< ::8[Z XnVlq }0/mO ,*MbK JH^6# 4`C|0 ?U=Sw uPsaq L4on2 Mjjh, ged)c '<$$p ]!};Y WiVxS eRQ>= ).K]l Ij"Fh gfedc b,=;z L\q%H X3E2C /ng-k N*KJI 8%6#D ~2^Ai >g<<d tUr`6 oJ"!1 /|{CU f)d>b <A_^! \};Yj yUxTS dtsr` ML
```

The original code:

```
bCBA@ ?>=<; :9876 54321 0/.-, +*)(' &%$#" !~}|{ zyxwv utsrq ponml kjihg fedcb a`_^] \[ZYX WVUTS RQPON MLKJI HGFED CBA@? >=<;: 9y165 43210 /.-,+ *)('& }C#"! ~wv<z \xwvu tsrqp onmlk jihgf e^$ba `_^W\ UyYXW VUTSR QPONM FKJIH GFEDC BA@9] =<;:9 27654 3210) M:
```

I cheated again by using a text-to-Malbolge generator for this code.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68219/34388)

Answer (score 2):

### [Labyrinth](https://github.com/mbuettner/labyrinth), 5 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67765/8478) by Adnan

```
_____
```

prints

```
000000
```

---

My original code was:

```
<!!@
```

Note the trailing space.

I suppose I should have gone for more characters and revealed one of the `!`, because Adnan's solution only grows linearly when adding more `!`, while mine grows quadratically.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67765/34388)

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 12 characters, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67769) by jimmy23013

**Output**

```
#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`
```

**Code**

```
_:____#_____
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67769/25180).

Answer (score 2):

<sup>Because I majorly f'ed up my last answer.</sup>

---

## [Mouse-2002](https://github.com/catb0t/mouse15), 23 chars, *safe*

Code:

```
________9<^___________
```

Output:

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`ab
```

Answer (score 2):

### ES6, 17 characters, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67801/41859) by Cᴏɴᴏʀ O'Bʀɪᴇɴ

```
__=____=_________
```

This is a function that will return the string

```
11233
```

Comment: I assume you mean JavaScript?

Comment: [Cracked?](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67801/41859)

Comment: FYI the original code was `(i=106)=>i*i-3+''`

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 28 characters

```
<?=________________________;
```

Outputs the string

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Comment: You should add that this was cracked.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 How would the OP know that if you delete your comment linking to the crack?

Comment: @MartinBüttner My crack was a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 83 chars, [Cracked by Martin Büttner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/67757/printing-ascending-ascii-robbers/67807#67807)

Output

```
Hi~~~
```

Code

```
_=____r____=u____=__s__=_________=__________________u_______A__________e______"_~_"
```

Output is in the JS console of a browser like Chrome/Firefox.

Original code (which *might* be invalid):

```
q=w=e=r=t=y=u=i=o=p=s=d=f=g=h=j=k=l=z=x=c=v=b=n=m="Huh"[0]+"Alarms in here"[7]+"~~~"
```

Comment: [Cracked?](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67807/8478)

Answer (score 2):

## [MirBSD Korn Shell](https://www.mirbsd.org/mksh.htm), 57 characters, safe

Output:

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

Code (57 characters):

> ___________*32____________127_____________________echo*$s

Revealed code:

> `local -i1 x=32;while((++x<127));do s+=${x:2};done;echo $s`

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 6 characters, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67868/34388) by Pietu1998

Code:

```
S_____
```

Output:

```
.0113345678888999
```

You can try Pyth [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67868/30164)

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 15 characters (safe)

Code:

```
_CM____________
```

Output:

```
"$%'()+-./013456789:;=?BCEFGIKLOPRSTUWXYZ[]^`abcdefghjklmoqsuvxy{|
```

[You can try Pyth online.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/)

> I wonder if you can find out the criteria for the characters. :3

Additional hint:

> One could have a computers firm like Captor's Fermium totally messed up on just this one puzzle, and still they wouldn't fully solve it. Even the actor Frump Mise couldn't solve it.

### Original code

> `sCMf%sPT3rCN127`

Explanation:

> `rCN127` generates all numbers from 34 (`CN` = `ord('"')`) to 127. `f%sPT3` finds all the ones that satisfy the following: the sum of the prime factors of `n` is not divisible by 3. `s` concatenates the results.
>
> The first hint has the number 3, and it refers to filtering the characters/numbers. The additional hint contains 3 anagrams of `prime factor sum`.

Answer (score 2):

## Octave, 18 bytes:

Output in Octave:

```
ans =  $'())**+,,--../0011233
```

Note that `ans =_` (replace `_` with space) is how Octave prints output by default and is not part of the output string. The output string alone starts with a single leading space like this:

```
 $'())**+,,--../0011233
```

Code:

```
[________:_______]
```

<sub>Disclaimer: If this miraculously should end up being the shortest uncracked submission, I'll award the win to the runner-up. This won't be a winning submission, I just wanted to have some fun too. *And* I figured a relatively short MATLAB/Octave submission could be fun for others. The other one was too hard for me at least.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript ES6, 134 characters

Huh boy, that was fun. Good luck!

```js
_=_=_____l____.______.________(___}__;___=______ru____"_____+_[________]______!____]__[_________e________.__U_________)__________\_____
```

Outputs:

`````
((((((()))))))+...000000000000000000002233=>AAAAAAAAAAABBBBBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCDDDDDDDEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEFFFFFFFGHIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIJJJJLLMMNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOPRRRRRRRSSSSTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTUUUUUUUUUVVVVVVXXY[[[[[[[[]]]]]]]]````ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiinnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu{{{{{{}}}}}}
`````

Comment: You are already safe.

Answer (score 2):

### [Seriously](http://seriouslylang.herokuapp.com), 7 bytes, [Cracked by Martin Büttner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67912/47050)

```
______S
```

Output:

```
   deeknnoow
```

Shouldn't be too difficult, even if the result is not exactly what you'd expect.

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67912/8478)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 58 characters, cracked by [Mitch Schwartz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68000/45032)

Code:

```
______________print(_______(_______________________)_____)
```

> import string;print(''.join(sorted(string.printable))[5:])

Output:

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68000/2537).

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68046/46231)

Comment: Oh, wait, Mitch's comment never loaded for me till now... that makes me really sad.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 32 characters, safe

Output (with no trailing newline):

```
!"#$%&'(+,./567;<HKLUVWnouvw
```

Obfuscated code:

```
________{|c|___________________}
```

Revealed code:

> 95.times{|c|c&5*c<7&&putc(c+33)}

Explanation:

> Actually pretty straight-forward, just too arbitrary to easily guess or brute-force. For each number c from 0 to 94, bitwise-and c and 5*c. If the result is less than 7, add 33 and output as an ASCII character.

Answer (score 2):

## Befunge, 11 characters, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68122/31203) (in funge-98) by MegaTom

Output:

```
1223788
```

Obfuscated code:

```
________.__
```

All one line, since the rules prohibit newlines. Tested using http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/befunge.html .

Edit: This is legally cracked since I didn't specify a version, but note that there's a Befunge-93 solution still out there.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68122/31203)

Answer (score 2):

### Perl 5, 30 bytes, [cracked](/a/68132) by [Adnan](/u/34388)

Code:

```
print_________________________
```

Output:

```
9:;@AFGHLMNRSTYZ_`a
```

Cracked:

[Adnan](/u/34388) found a [trivial](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triviality_%28mathematics%29) [crack](/a/68132): obviously, I didn't think this puzzle through well enough. I've composed [another](/a/68142) instead.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 62 chars, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68239/34388) by [Adnan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/34388/adnan)

```
______________________________________________________________
         | |   ||                  |  |  ||
```

It kinda looks like a table.

This outputs the string `abcde`.

Adnan's code:

> `print "ab_c_de___".replace("_","")#___________________________`

My code:

> `f=lamda _,__,___:"abcde"+'f'*sum(_,__,___)*000;print f(1,2,3);`

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68239/34388)

Comment: I am allowed to use comments, right?

Comment: I don't know.  I specifically said when I posted it there were no comments.  I don't know if I can do that though.  I commented on the OP and asked.  We'll see what he says.

Comment: *You can not use comments (but the robbers can use comments when cracking the code)* (CC @Adnan)

Comment: Awww. @Rikerw is sad now.

Answer (score 2):

## Octave,  22 characters, Safe

Code:

```
__A____________A___V__
```

Output:

```
ans = ABCDFGHHIJLMNNOPRSTTUV
```

`ans =` is not part of the output. The output starts with an `A`.

Real code:

> [(A=66:86)+sin(A),'V']

Explanation:

> In Octave, variable assignments can be done in the same line they are used. So, the variable `A` is created starting from `66` (corresponds to `A` in ASCII) to `86` (corresponds to `V` in ASCII). `+sin(A)` creates a small sine wave noise. `'V` converts the vector to chars and adds a `V` at the end. The variable name `A` and the last letter `V` was of course chosen to throw people of track =)

This one was made for the robbers. Hope it's neither too hard nor too easy. Good luck :-)

Answer (score 1):

## Marbelous, 39 characters (safe)

_ is an unknown character: it may or may not be a newline.

* represents a newline character.

```
__^__________*__<___________@___/_*____
```

Output:

```
%,:>?@@BBFFNN^^~~
```

Code:

```
@0^5FF
0101FC
\\<ZEE
<</\+S
@0+Z//
25--
```

[Online interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40808/29611). None of the options should be checked.

Comment: Unfortunately, the code can only consist of printable ASCII.

Comment: OP's comment: This is a valid post, although it says in the challenge that only printable ASCII characters should be used in the code. I confirmed to es1024 that newlines could be used. This will be the only exception to this rule.

Comment: @StewieGriffin Do you mean than nobody else can use newlines; only es1024 in this answer is allowed to use them?

Comment: Not allowing newlines effectively excludes Marbelous from these challenges. No non-trivial program can be written in mbl without vertical movement of marbles.

Comment: @Sparr I don't see how the comments on this answer are agreeing with you. If nobody else can use newlines, then you can't either.

Comment: @cat es1024 was told by the author of the question that newlines can be used in this answer. it is unclear whether "this will be the only exception" applies to just this answer, or just to es1024, or just to Marbelous.

Answer (score 1):

## [Recall](https://github.com/minxomat/Recall), 64 characters

Output:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

Code:

```
_D_0__0_M__________0__0___0_________Z___0____0_____________M____
```

Pretty straightforward in theory. I made a sandbox [here](http://minxomat.github.io/Recall/index.html?code=_D_0__0_M__________0__0___0_________Z___0____0_____________M____), so you can try things. Keep in mind that infinite loops or deep recursion will crash your tab/browser, so keep a copy elsewhere when trying. You can also download `recall.min.js` from the link in the title and run it with node.js.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 68 characters, safe

As usual, don't expect anything short from PHP:

```
______________________________1_________________________________[1_;
 |    |    |           |               |           |    |      |
```

Outputs this 252 character long string:

```
AAAAAAAABCCDDEEEEEEEGIIIIIKLMNNOOOOOOOOOPPPPRSSTTTUUUUUXYYZaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbccccccccccccdddddddeeeeeeeeeeeeeffffffggghhhhiiiiiiiiiiiklllllllllllllllmmmmmmnnnnnnnnnnooooooooooooooopppppppppppppqrrrrrrrrrrrrrrsssssssssssssssssstttttttttuuuuuuuuuwxyyyzzz
```

**Hint 1**

> Sometimes you have to "translate" things.

**Hint 2**

> Luckily PHP stores all those helpful "translations" for you internally.

**Revealed code**

> There aren't too many built in functions, that return long strings or arrays with predefined values. One exception is [`get_html_translation_table`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-html-translation-table.php). I sorted this array and returned the first character after the `&` from all escape sequences, e.g. the *A* from `&Auml;`. It has a nice distribution which looks random because the amount of entities related to a letter varies a lot.
>  `$_=get_html_translation_table(1);sort($_);foreach($_ as$_)echo$_[1];`
>  `______________________________1_________________________________[1_;`
>  `>|    |    |           |               |           |    |      |`

Comment: `Unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM`?

Comment: @cat Hihi. But it might be a different kind of translation. ;)

Answer (score 1):

## [Milky Way 1.6.1](https://github.com/zachgates7/Milky-Way), 24 characters, Safe

Output:

```
jklmnopqrt
```

Code (24 characters):

```
^_"_________________"__!
```

---

#### Solution

```
^^"pqrjklmno"C=<<<"t"JG!
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 61 characters

Gonna try again, if that's okay :p I wasn't expecting `range('a','z')` to be particularly well-known, but I should have known better around here ;)

Code:

```
<?p___________++<_______h__________e______1____p_____________
```

Outputs:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCDDDDDDEEEEEEFFFFFGGGGGHHHHHIIIIJJJJKKKKLLLMMMNNNNOOOPPP
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 76 characters, [Cracked by Adnan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/67757/printing-ascending-ascii-robbers/68017#68017)

```
print __________h______________________v_____________,___)_________)_______)
```

Outputs

```
BKT]f
```

Full Code

> `print "".join([chr(x) for x in list(reversed(range(32,126)[70:5:-9]))[3:8]])`

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68017/34388)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 characters, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68188/34388) by quintopia

Obfuscated code:

```
___T___
```

Original code:

```
576T*uH

576      # Pushes 576
   T     # Pushes 10
    *    # Multiply the last two items of the stack
     u   # To uppercase, this just returns 576 in string format
      H  # Convert from hexadecimal to decimal
```

**Note:** I used the uppercase command to convert the int to a string. This however is a bug and has already been fixed.

Output:

```
22368
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68188/47050)

Answer (score 1):

### Seriously, 7 characters, (uncracked and noncompeting)

I was inspired by trying to find an answer to Adnan's latest cop, by how close this number was to their number:

```
___P___
```

Output:

```
22366
```

> 22366 is the 211th triangular number. The original program was `8PτPurΣ` but it is disqualified for containing two non-ASCII characters. It simply takes the 8th prime (23), doubles it (46), finds the 46th prime (211), then pushes the 0-211 range (`ur`) and sums it.

Comment: Just to confirm, this code contains only printable ASCII?

Comment: No. Guess I missed that requirement. Thought only the output had to be printable ascii. Well I can tell you it consists only of printable CP-437 characters.

Comment: Since this doesn't meet the criteria, I suggest you [edit] it to note that it and its robbers are noncompeting.

Comment: But I don't want it's robbers to be noncompeting! Can't the robbers get credit for cracking it even when it is not a legal cop?

Answer (score 1):

## Marbelous, 19 characters

```
_1
___0
____
_____1
```

Outputs

```
39?E(
```

Comment: "Write a program or function consisting *only of printable ASCII characters* **(that excludes tab and newline)...**"

Comment: @cat check the comments on the other Marbelous submission

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 6 characters ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67890/30164) by isaacg)

Output:

```
qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
```

Code:

```
S_____
```

Let's try a simpler one.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67890/20080)

Answer (score 0):

### [Purple](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65411/golf-a-purple-interpreter), 31 characters (safe)

```
__A_____________o______b__1___b
```

Full program:

> `a1AbA1iib{bi1b1Bo1aaa1bbab1Bi1b`

Output:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Explanation:

> It's about the shortest way to print the alphabet in Purple.
>
> ```
> 1.  a1A    Set to 1-"a" == -96
> 2.  bA1    Set b to -1 (using the fact that a is always negative)
> 3.  iib{   Set i=i-b, i.e. i+1. This skips over the "{"
> 4.  bi1    Set b = i-1 (the cell before the current command, containing "{")
> 5.  b1B    Set b = 1-"{" == -122
> 6.  o1a    Output 1-a (which will be the current character)
> 7.  aa1    Subtract 1 from a (i.e. move to the next character)
> 8.  bba    Set b=b-a. It will be negative until a==-122, when it will be zero
> 9.  b1B    Set b=1-what b points to. It will be 0 until a==-122, when it will be -96.
> 10. i1b    Jump to 1-b. This goes to line 2 until a==-122, when it jumps outside 
>            the program and halts.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

## Unefunge-98, 16

Output:

```
&),/258;>ADGJMPSVY\_behknqtwz}
```

Code:

```
_#_________3____
```

Answer (score 0):

### Perl 5, 31 bytes, safe

Code:

```
print__________________________
```

Output:

```
$%&&'+,,-1223478899:>??@DEEFJKKLLMPQRRSWXXY]^^_
```

Code:

> `print+(chr)x(1.2+cos)for 36..95`

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 59 characters

Output:

`````````````
   """'''(((((())))))+++++++++,,,,,,---------...............123:::===>>>???NNNNNNOOO[[[[[[\\\]]]]]]^^^______````````````aaabbbbbbccccccddeeeeeeeefgggggggggggghhhiiiijjjjjjjjjkkklllllllllnnnnnooooooooorrrssstttttttttu{{{}}}
`````````````

The first 3 characters in the output are spaces.

Code:

```
(_____________________________________________.join``_____)
```

*Note: The original version of this produced a much greater variation in characters with the exact same code hint, but I thought the output was unreasonably long so I decided that I'd at least give someone a chance at cracking this. :P Good luck!*

Comment: You are already safe.

Answer (score 0):

## Forth, 29 chars

You're gonna need a very special version of Forth for this one: one that doesn't require newlines after function definitions.

Code

```
_______ __ _________ ____ ___
```

(Yes, that's whitespace, and yes, it has to be there or else one gets `Error: Unknown word`)

Output:

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

Note the leading space.

Answer (score 0):

## CJam, 9 chars

Code:

```
'_{___2__
```

Output:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68231)

Answer (score 0):

## Brainfuck, 51 chars

Code

```
_____[________________]>.>_____[________]>[_______]
```

Output:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Comment: `+++++[>+++++++++++++<-]>.>+++++[>+++++<-]>[<<+.>>-]`

Comment: @Mitch Schwartz wow, it's exactly the same as real code

Answer (score 0):

## Python2, 72 chars

Code:

```
___(___(___(___((_____)_(____)_)______________(______)________________)
```

[Full output (63,769,891 bytes) as compressed by `zlib` (use `import zlib; zlib.decompress(...)` to get the actual string, which I recommend writing to a file)](http://pastebin.com/JzPguaYz)

Comment: Shouldn't this reveal 12 characters?

Comment: @Dennis it absolutely should, I pasted the wrong version (after I added bytes.)

Comment: can you provide a run-length-encoded version of the output for easier analysis?

Comment: yeah, sure, gimmie a sec

Comment: @quintopia [here ya go](http://pastebin.com/MZ2Vee8M)

Comment: @cat how many of each digit is there? I assume that one really large number would say, but I'm not sure how to partition it.

Comment: @quintopia sorry, here, [this](http://pastebin.com/wH4wscXu) might make it clearer

Comment: @quintopia did the second link help?

Comment: Yes, but I haven't had time to work on it yet.

Answer (score 0):

## [CLC-INTERCAL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/CLC-INTERCAL) 1.-98.-2, 198 bytes, safe.

33 bytes are revealed:

```
__#3__#9__,1_____________________________3__3__-_3__3__________-_33_D_______&_________-_____________-___D_#4__#28D______________-________B#__-_V________________-_V_______________________________U___
```

Output is:

```
!->Ma
```

Should I post shorter one next time?

[Try it online!](http://golf.shinh.org/check.rb)

### Answer

Sorry for irrationally difficult problem.

> `DO#3<-#9DO,1<-#3DO,1SUB#3<-#3~#3DO,1SUB'#3~#3'<-#3~#3DO,1SUB#5<-#338DO,1SUB"&'#3~#3'"<-#27DO,1SUB#4<-#27DO#4<-#28DO,1SUB'#4~#4'<-#4DO,1SUB#6<-"V'#V4'"DO,1SUB#8<-'V"V'#V4'"'DO,1SUB#2<-#333DOREADOUT,1`

#### How it works

> `DO#3<-#9` changes meaning of the constant.

> `DO,1<-#3` lets array to have nine item; note previous statement.

> `DO,1SUB#3<-#3~#3` is equivalent to `DO,1SUB#9<-#9~#9`, which is equivalent to `DO,1SUB#9<-#3`.

> `DO,1SUB'#3~#3'<-#3~#3` does `,1SUB#3<-#3`.

> `DO,1SUB#5<-#338` is equal to `DO,1SUB#5<-#18` when `READ`ing `OUT`; this is how Baudot character set works; it cares for only lower five octets.

> `DO,1SUB"&'#3~#3'"<-#27` does `,1SUB#1<-#27`.

> `DO,1SUB#4<-#27` is obvious, as none of those constants are not overloaded yet.

> `DO#4<-#28` now overloads the operand.

> `DO,1SUB'#4~#4'<-#4` now does `,1SUB#7<-#28`.

> `DO,1SUB#6<-"V'#V4'"` is actually `DO,1SUB#6<-#30`.

> `DO,1SUB#8<-'V"V'#V4'"'` does `,1SUB#8<-#31`

> `DO,1SUB#2<-#333` does what it says.

> Finally, output is done by `DOREADOUT,1`.

By the way the reason why an array requires 9 items to output 5 characters is: tail arrays adopt extended Baudot character set. The character set has a concept of "state": uppercase, lowercase, figures, and symbols. When a same value is READ OUT with different state, the different character is READ OUT

Answer (score 0):

## [CLC-INTERCAL](https://esplangs.org/wiki/CLC-INTERCAL), 38 bytes, safe.

This is much easier than previous.
Six bytes are revealed:

```
____<-___________<-________DO_________
```

Outputs:

```
BCDLX
```

[Try it online!](http://golf.shinh.org/check.rb)

### The answer

> `DO;1<-#1DO;1SUB#1<-#17DOREADOUT;1+#460`

> Please note output is "B" and "CDLX".

Comment: Sorry for having made problems that nobody really cares.