# Printing ascending ASCII, Robbers

Tags: cops-and-robbers

This is the robbers' thread. The cops' thread [goes here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/67756/printing-ascending-ascii-cops).

In the cops thread, the task was to create a program that outputs printable ASCII characters in ascending order. The robbers task is to unscramble the code the cops used to produce this output.

The cracked code doesn't have to be identical, as long as it has the same length and any revealed characters are in the correct positions. The language must also be the same (version numbers can be different). The output must of course be identical. Cops can not use comments in their code, but robbers are free to use them.

The winner of the robbers thread will be the user who has cracked the
most submissions by January 7th 2016. If there's a tie, the user who has cracked submissions with the longest combined code will win.

The submission should be formatted like this:

## Language, nn characters (including link to answer), Cop's username

Code:

```
alphaprinter
```

Output

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Optional explanation and comments.

## Leaderboard:

**A crushing victory by [Adnan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/34388/adnan)!**

```
Adnan: 7
Pietu1998: 3
Mitch Schwartz: 2
Quintopia: 2
Martin Büttner: 2
cat: 1
Dennis: 1
insertusernamehere: 1
isaacg: 1
jimmy23013: 1
MegaTom: 1
plannapus: 1
user81655: 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [Python 2, 76 characters, wnnmaw](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68009/34388)

Code, with obfuscated version below:

```
print "BKT]f"#__h______________________v_____________,___)_________)_______)
print __________h______________________v_____________,___)_________)_______)
```

This outputs `BKT]f`. Not the intended version, that's for sure haha.

Tested [here](http://mathcs.holycross.edu/%7Ekwalsh/python/)

Comment: Sneaky comments :)

Comment: That'll teach you to post a program whose output is shorter than the length of the program in a language that has `print` unless you have revealed characters in exactly the places the string would have to sit.

Answer (score 7):

## [Brainfuck, 48 bytes, Adnan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67787/2537)

```
++++[>++++[>++++<-]<-]+++[>++++++++<-]>++[>+.<-]
```

Pretty straightforward, generating 64 and then 26. It might be a little red herring that

```
++++[>++++[>++++<-]<-]>>+
```

is a way to get 65, so you might try to do something like

```
++++[>++++[>++++<-]<-]>>+[>+++++>++<<-----]>>[<.+>-]
```

before noticing that it's a dead end.

Comment: Ahhh, well done :)

Answer (score 6):

## [CJam, 12 characters, Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67766/25180)

```
":0[Aa#":,:^
```

It's in the tips...

Comment: Right, I had forgotten about the tips...

Answer (score 6):

## [CJam, 8 characters, Martin Büttner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67809/30164)

Code (with blanked code):

```
{`:)$}_~
__:_____
```

Output:

```
%*;a|~
```

[Try it online.](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=e2A6KSR9X34&input=)

I sort of had a feeling about this from the moment I saw it. And I thought I didn't know CJam...

Answer (score 5):

## [Labyrinth, 5 characters, Martin Büttner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67762/34388)

Code:

```
!!!>@
```

[Test it here](http://labyrinth.tryitonline.net/#code=ISEhPkA&input=)

Output:

```
000000
```

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (ES6), 17 characters, Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67797/41859)

As the OP posted a function, here's a solution using a function:

```
()=>xxx=11000+233
__=____=_________
```

The anonymous function can be invoked like:

```
(()=>xxx=11000+233)();
```

A more ridiculous solution I had at first:

```
xx=yyyy=z=11230+3
__=____=_________
```

When run in the console, it will print the number `11233`.

Comment: Ninja'd me. I got `fx=asdf=>  "11233"`

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Thought, I had to be fast on this one. :D

Comment: Well, kudos to you on your fastest gun in the west. +1

Comment: -1 for no strings :P

Comment: @BlockCoder1392 Hehe. I refactored my solutions. At first I had `xx=yyyy=z="11233"` which will literally return `"11233"` which is not the same as `11233`. That's why I took the addition approach. :)

Comment: However, +1 for `xx=yyyy=z=11230+3`

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ's version seems to be the only one that's a function that returns a string.

Comment: @Neil I can easily adopt that to be a real string, If you read the comment to BlockCoder you can see, why I changed it. Is it really necessary on PPCG for JavaScript to return an explicit string? If so, I'm happy to change that.

Comment: If I didn't think it had to return a string I wouldn't have made my function return a string.

Answer (score 4):

## [PHP, 28 characters, Niet the Dark Absol](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67800/34388)

I found several versions for this task:

**Original version:**

```
<?=@implode(range('a','z'));
```

**My version:**

```
<?=join('',range('a', 'z'));
```

**23 character version:**

```
<?=join('',range(a,z));
```

**26 character version:**

```
<?=implode('',range(a,z));
```

Of course, you can just add several whitespaces to get to the 28 character mark.

Tested [here](http://codepad.org/)

Comment: Dang, you beat me :P The shortest I can do: `<?=join(range(a,z));`

Comment: You got me - maybe I should have made it more restrictive by putting one of the letters of a function name as the revealed characters... Anyway, for the record, here's the original: `<?=@implode(range('a','z'));`

Answer (score 4):

## [Jolf, 27 characters, Cᴏɴᴏʀ O'Bʀɪᴇɴ](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67804/34388)

After a few hours of trial and error, I got it haha:

```
on-pl'u'Wa-n"vwxyz"`--'01_2
```

Including obfuscated code:

```
on-pl'u'Wa-n"vwxyz"`--'01_2
________W___________--_____
                         |
```

Try it [here](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=b24tcGwndSdXYS1uInZ3eHl6ImAtLScwMV8y) (**step run** seems to be the only one working with alert)

---

#### Explanation

First thing I got stuck on was the placement of the while loop. I didn't seem to get it on the right place haha. After getting it right, the second thing I noticed was the placement of the underscore. I thought I almost got it, until I got stuck on the underscore (gg Cᴏɴᴏʀ O'Bʀɪᴇɴ).

Here is full explanation of the code:

```
on-pl'u'Wa-n"vwxyz"`--'01_2

o                           # assign
 n                          # n / standard variable
   pl                       # pl = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
  -  'u                     # pl - "u" = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstvwxyz"
       'W                   # a string in the middle doing nothing
          -n"vwxyz"         # n - "vwxyz"
         a                  # alert(
                   `        # is an extra semicolon
                     -'01   # "0" - 1
                    -    _2 # ("0" - 1) - negative 2
```

In pseudocode:

```
n = minus("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", "u");
"W";
alert(minus(n,"vwxyz"));
;
minus(minus("0", 1), negative(2));
```

I'm interested to see what the actual solution was :)

Comment: holy mother of God not what I intended o______o but nice job, anyhow! I posted the actual code on my answer.

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth, 6 bytes, Pietu1998](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67888/20080)

```
Ssy>TG
```

Take the last 10 letters of the alphabet, form all subsets, concatenate, sort.

Answer (score 4):

## [R, 60 bytes, Fax Machine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67878/6741)

Code:

```
cat(c(0:9,LETTERS[1:8],LETTERS[20:26],letters[4:23]),sep="")
```

Output:

```
0123456789ABCDEFGHTUVWXYZdefghijklmnopqrstuvw
```

Answer (score 4):

### [Seriously, 7 characters, by quintopia](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67898/8478)

```
2'aNsES
```

[Tested here.](http://seriouslylang.herokuapp.com/link/code=3227614e734553&input=)

Splits 99 bottles of beer around `a`s and sorts the third chunk.

Comment: I used the 7th chunk, but the result is the same. Knew this one would be a cinch ;)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3, 58 bytes, Mathias Ettinger](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67946/2537)

```
import string;print(''.join(sorted(string.printable))[5:])
```

Basic use of [string](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/string.html) module.

Comment: I didn't see that you'd cracked this before me, I tried using `string` but didn't think of using `sorted` (because I forget it exists). I don't know if I should leave my crack up, since it's nowhere near the same method but it works.

Comment: @cat I don't know what Stewie Griffin's opinion would be about that, but anyway I gave you +1 and think it makes sense to keep your answer up since it's not the same answer as mine.

Answer (score 4):

### [05AB1E, 13 characters, Adnan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67759/47050)

Code (and blanked code):

```
1TD*<F3<*}bRJ
__D____<_____
```

Output:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
```

Explanation:

```
1                       Push 1
 TD*<                   Push 99
     F   }              For loop
      3<*               multiply top of stack by 3-1 (e.g. double it)
          b             convert to list of binary digits (note we have just computed 2^99)
           R            reverse it
            J           join it into a string.
                        (top of stack implicitly printed)
```

Comment: Woooww!! Amazing job :)

Answer (score 3):

### [JavaScript, 83 characters, BlockCoder1392](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67806/8478)

```
a=aaaaraaaa=uaaaa=aasaa=console;b=0;a.log("Hi~~~");auaaaaaaaAaaaaaaaa =aeaaaa="^~^"
```

A bit too many characters for such a short string.

Answer (score 3):

### [JavaScript (ES6), 60 characters, insertusernamehere](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67812)

Code:

```js
e=e=>{try{a}catch(e){return[...e.toString()].sort().join``}}
e_e_______a__a____e___e________e__o___________o______o______
```

Output (in Chrome):

```
    :ERacddeeeeeeffiinnnoorrrrst
```

I knew this immediately because I was about to do the same thing! xD

Comment: Nice one - character by character. :D

Comment: @insertusernamehere You could have done `[...e+'']` to make it a bit shorter. That threw me off at the start. ;)

Comment: What does `return[...e.toString()]` actually do? I only know a lil JS...

Comment: @cat It just puts each letter of the error message into an array. It needs to do this because `sort` only works on arrays, not strings.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth, 6 characters, Adnan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67853/30164)

Code (with blanked code):

```
S`.n 3
S_____
```

Output

```
.0113345678888999
```

[Try it online.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=S%60.n%203&debug=0)

It's φ's representation, sorted. This could've been done in 5, if you remove the space.

Comment: Awww, I forgot about the backticks :p. My original code was `S+.n3"`

Answer (score 3):

## [Malbolge, 254 characters, frederick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68198/34388)

Obfuscated version:

```
_____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ __
```

My version:

```
('&%: ^"!65 4Xzyx w4-Qs rpo'K mlk"' ~Dfdc ba}v< ::8[Z XnVlq }0/mO ,*MbK JH^6# 4`C|0 ?U=Sw uPsaq L4on2 Mjjh, ged)c '<$$p ]!};Y WiVxS eRQ>= ).K]l Ij"Fh gfedc b,=;z L\q%H X3E2C /ng-k N*KJI 8%6#D ~2^Ai >g<<d tUr`6 oJ"!1 /|{CU f)d>b <A_^! \};Yj yUxTS dtsr` ML
```

This will output:

```
`AB\cd`
```

You can try it [here](http://zb3.github.io/malbolge-tools/#interpreter).

Answer (score 2):

<sup>This answer is invalid and shouldn't count towards my score (not that I'm anywhere near winning anyways) because I didn't see it had already been cracked.</sup>

## [Python 3, 58 characters, Mathias Ettinger](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67946/46231)

Code, with original code below:

```
x=range(95);  print(''.join((chr(i+32) for i in x  )    ))
______________print(_______(_______________________)_____)
```

Clearly not the intended solution, which was:

```
import string;print(''.join(sorted(string.printable))[5:])
```

Output:

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

(Note the leading space.)

A fun one to crack: it took me a while to figure how to get the `genexpr` to work properly. :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Befunge, 11 characters, histocrat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68026/31203)

Code:

```
89'**'z...@
```

Output:

```
1223788
```

That was fun. This is an alternate solution I also found:

```
8]..@#37.z'
```

Comment: Oh, cool, funge-98 solutions.

Answer (score 2):

### [05AB1E, 7 characters Adnan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68141/47050)

Code and blanked code:

```
576T*uH
___T___
```

Output:

```
22368
```

Explanation:

```
576       Push this number.
   T      Push ten.
    *     Multiply. (5760)
     u    Convert to string.
      H   Interpret as a hex number and push decimal (22368) (implicit output).
```

I almost positive this wasn't the original program, but thanks to Adnan for providing the one bit of information that made it possible (the `u` command).

Comment: I think this was the original program haha. Well done :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth, 17 characters, Luke](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67768/30164)

Code (with blanked code):

```
S`u]G6*T`t"#X0231
___________#____1
```

Output:

```
""''''''''''''''''''''0000000000111111111122222222223333333333XXXXXXXXXX[[[[[[]]]]]]
```

[Try it online.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=S%60u]G6*T%60t%22%23X0231&debug=0)

This was fun. I got it to 18 bytes multiple times using `#` as the filter operator, but then I figured out I could just discard it from the string. If you remove the `t` and the `#` the result would probably be the shortest Pyth code for that output.

Basically:

- `"#X0231` makes the string `#X0231`
- `t"#X0231` removes the `#`: `X0231`
- `` `t"#X0231 `` gets the string representation: `'X0231'`
- `` *T`t"#X0231 `` multiplies it by 10: `'X0231''X0231''X0231'`…
- `` u]G6*T`t"#X0231 `` wraps it in an array 6 times
- `` `u]G6*T`t"#X0231 `` gets the string representation: `[[[[[['X0231'`…`'X0231']]]]]]`
- `` S`u]G6*T`t"#X0231 `` sorts it to get the output

Comment: Very nice! And pretty different from what I had done.

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam, 9 characters, by username.ak](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68204)

```
'a{_)}25*
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=J2F7Xyl9MjUq&input=)

#### How it works

```
'a         e# Push the character 'a'.
  {  }25*  e# Do 25 times.
   _       e# Copy the character on the stack.
    )      e# Increment the copy.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5, 30 characters, msh210](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68119/34388)

Obfuscated + my version:

```
print_________________________
print "9:;\@AFGHLMNRSTYZ_`a"
```

This will output:

```
9:;@AFGHLMNRSTYZ_`a
```

Tested [here](http://codepad.org/WvTdnhzD)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2, 62 characters, RikerW](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68200/34388)

Obfuscated version:

```
______________________________________________________________
         | |   ||                  |  |  ||
```

My version:

```
print "ab_c_de___".replace("_","")#___________________________
```

This simply removes all the underscores and outputs `abcde`.

Tried it [here](http://mathcs.holycross.edu/%7Ekwalsh/python/)