# XOR sort an array

Tags: code-golf, string, array, sorting, bitwise

Given a key, and an array of strings, shuffle the array so that it is sorted when each element is XOR'd with the key.

### XOR'ing two strings

To XOR a string by a key, XOR each of the character values of the string by its pair in the key, assuming that the key repeats forever. For example, `abcde^123` looks like:

```
       a        b        c        d        e
       1        2        3        1        2
--------------------------------------------
01100001 01100010 01100011 01100100 01100101
00110001 00110010 00110011 00110001 00110010
--------------------------------------------
01010000 01010000 01010000 01010101 01010111
--------------------------------------------
       P        P        P        U        W
```

### Sorting

Sorting should always be done Lexicographically of the XOR'd strings. That is, `1 < A < a < ~` (Assuming ASCII encoding)

### Example

```
"912", ["abcde", "hello", "test", "honk"]

-- XOR'd
["XSQ]T", "QT^U^", "MTAM", "Q^\R"]
-- Sorted
["MTAM", "QT^U^", "Q^\R", "XSQ]T"]
-- Converted back
["test", "hello", "honk", "abcde"]
```

### Notes

- Key will always be at least 1 character
- Key and Input will only consist of printable ASCII.
- XOR'd strings may contain non-printable characters.
- Input and Output may be done through the [Reasonable Methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)
- [Standard Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- You may take Key and Input in any order.

### Test Cases

```
key, input -> output
--------------------
"912", ["abcde", "hello", "test", "honk"] -> ["test", "hello", "honk", "abcde"]
"taco", ["this", "is", "a", "taco", "test"] -> ["taco", "test", "this", "a", "is"]
"thisisalongkey", ["who", "what", "when"] -> ["who", "what", "when"]
"3", ["who", "what", "when"] -> ["what", "when", "who"]
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so least bytes wins!

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/68109/61563) nowhere near a dupe though

Comment: Are the strings guaranteed to be different?

Comment: @Neil Although I can't imagine a situation where them being identical would cause problems, you can assume that all strings will be unique.

Comment: @ATaco It can certainly matter if you're not using built-in string comparison.

Comment: Should have been called "XORt an array" :p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>9</s> 7 bytes

```
⁹ṁO^OµÞ
```

*Thanks to @EriktheOutgolfer for a suggestion that helped saving 2 bytes!*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R486HOxv94/wPbT087//h5Ub67v//RyslJiWnpCrpKChlAJXlgxglqcUlYIH8vGylWCDD0tAIyI9WKsnILAZJQMhEsNrEZISeWIRAtFJ5BliiPCOxBEKn5kEUAA3JLE7Myc9Lz06txKvUWAkA)

#### How it works

```
⁹ṁO^OµÞ  Dyadic link.
         Left argument: A (string array). Right argument: k (key string).

     µ   Combine the code to the left into a chain.
         Begin a new, monadic chain with argument A.
      Þ  Sort A, using the chain to the left as key.
         Since this chain is monadic, the key chain will be called monadically,
         once for each string s in A.
⁹            Set the return value to the right argument of the link (k).
 ṁ           Mold k like s, i.e., repeat its characters as many times as necessary
             to match the length of s.
  O          Ordinal; cast characters in the resulting string to their code points.
    O        Do the same for the chain's argument (s).
   ^         Perform bitwise XOR.
```

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>75</s> 73 bytes

```python
lambda k,x:x.sort(key=lambda s:[ord(x)^ord(y)for x,y in zip(s,k*len(s))])
```

This sorts the list **x** in-place.

*Thanks to @mercator for golfing off 2 bytes!*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY/BDoMgEETP@hWEE9uQJq2nmvRLrE1QsRAoGCER@/MWsF572ZnsvE1mp9ULa6ptRHf02DR7dwNDioY6nJ2dPVF8vf@2rm7sPJAAzyQrjHZGga5IGvSRE3FUnTQ3xAG0sKWQKIoCpJyUBcG3yxVT1GDW9QOPDguutU3Gc@fzwhqFW6CJ9qy3GfdCuhTuk2V@z/a7g4@YdExb84qd8@UiMrUI5nfl5qCrP0AJdVmMsXyAsphmaXz8efsC)

#### Alternate version, 62 bytes

This takes input as byte strings, which may not be allowed.

```python
lambda k,x:x.sort(key=lambda s:[*map(int.__xor__,s,k*len(s))])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY/BCoQgGITP@RTiSRcJdjtt0JO0EVq2iqaRQvb0rWR03NM/zMwH/yx7kM5WxwQb@DkMm/nIoKaxjqV3a8Ba7M3l@rp9zGzByoay76Nb@556qh9GWOwJ6cgxuRViTWEkUFmIQYE5ej9fiMKWI8aHUSTJkRTGuFMF4UO2nNWoI/REAhtcZoJU/syvwzKV8wu/qdRVnhlnv@npzG8yFzfJwiWEvYnqfwmQGhRT2hMJKJY1zcaRHD8)

Comment: In-place sorting saves 2 bytes: `x.sort(key=...)`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 61 bytes

```ruby
->k,w{w.sort_by{|x|x.bytes.zip(k.bytes.cycle).map{|x,y|x^y}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY2xDoIwGIR3n4LUAU0KCTA5yIuQagoWS0BKoKZU4NmxtGA6GOPSu9z997V9pnLOz7MXl1AMwu9Yy6@pHMZ@7P1UctL5r6I5lKvPZFaRo//AjbqAcuwvcpqmuXHyxA3CyIWJi9PsRlyEdksITkEIoJMAnSoHKKkqthiF4zpgdQkQcvaOF6vDT7zd6V6pIaxYjjOmuZwW3dKaF2uw6QzJAtvxotTaKLuRVVx0uGL1vSRS/yGoHgqKuVFSW9yvrWFFf82tWCvb5vjHfH4D)

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, 77 bytes

```
import Data.Bits
import Data.List
t=fromEnum
sortOn.zipWith((.t).xor.t).cycle
```

Too many imports.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY0xC8IwEIX3/IojOFSQgDo5dBHdBEcH6XCmKQltktKcVP3zMWkR1OXe8d77eBpDq7ouRmN7PxAckFDsDQX2bZxMIEZlM3h7dHfLmjKk7OzEy/QXQ7ooBC3Fww9Z5FN2Klo0DkqoPQPoB@MIFtAA3603HODK8SZrxVfAdVr3@SEVaDK8a3n1SxFKzxNF2oTcmS9OWI4@@B@2TVN5bNRTZdRIsyrHK4hv)

Answer (score 3):

## x86 opcode, 57 Bytes

```
0100  60 89 CD 4D 8B 74 8A FC-8B 3C AA 53 F6 03 FF 75
0110  02 5B 53 8A 23 AC 08 C0-74 0A 30 E0 32 27 47 43
0120  38 E0 74 E8 77 0A 8B 04-AA 87 44 8A FC 89 04 AA
0130  85 ED 5B 75 CE E2 CA 61-C3

    ;input ecx(length), edx(array), ebx(xor-d)
F:  pushad
L1: mov ebp, ecx
L2: dec ebp
    mov esi, [edx+ecx*4-4]
    mov edi, [edx+ebp*4]
    push ebx
L6: test [ebx], byte -1 ; t1b
    jnz L4
    pop ebx
    push ebx
L4: mov ah, [ebx]
    lodsb
    or  al, al
    jz  L7
    xor al, ah
    xor ah, [edi]
    inc edi
    inc ebx
    cmp al, ah
    jz  L6
L7: ja  L8
    mov eax, dword[edx+ebp*4]
    xchg eax, dword[edx+ecx*4-4]
    mov dword[edx+ebp*4], eax
L8: ;call debug
    test ebp, ebp
    pop ebx
    jnz L2
    loop L1
    popad
    ret
```

Test code:

```
if 1
    use32
else
    org $0100
    mov ecx, (Qn-Q0)/4
    mov edx, Q0
    mov ebx, S
    call F
    call debug
    ret

debug:pushad
    mov ecx, (Qn-Q0)/4
    mov edx, Q0
    mov ebx, S
E3:   mov esi, [edx]
    push dx
    mov ah, 2
E4:   lodsb
    cmp al, 0
    jz E5
    mov dl, al
    int $21
    jmp E4
E5:   mov dl, $0A
    int $21
    mov dl, $0D
    int $21
    pop dx
    add edx, 4
    loop E3
    ;mov ah, 1
    ;int $21
    int1
    popad
    ret
    align 128
Q0:
    dd str1, str2, str3, str4
Qn:
S     db '912', 0
str1  db 'abcde', 0
str2  db 'hello', 0
str3  db 'test', 0
str4  db 'honk', 0
    align 128
end if
    ;input ecx(length), edx(array), ebx(xor-d)
F:  pushad
L1: mov ebp, ecx
L2: dec ebp
    mov esi, [edx+ecx*4-4]
    mov edi, [edx+ebp*4]
    push ebx
L6: test [ebx], byte -1 ; t1b
    jnz L4
    pop ebx
    push ebx
L4: mov ah, [ebx]
    lodsb
    or  al, al
    jz  L7
    xor al, ah
    xor ah, [edi]
    inc edi
    inc ebx
    cmp al, ah
    jz  L6
L7: ja  L8
    mov eax, dword[edx+ebp*4]
    xchg eax, dword[edx+ecx*4-4]
    mov dword[edx+ebp*4], eax
L8: ;call debug
    test ebp, ebp
    pop ebx
    jnz L2
    loop L1
    popad
    ret
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript ES 6, <s>113</s> <s>97</s> 95 Bytes

```
k=>p=>p.sort((a,b,F=x=>[...x].map((y,i)=>1e9|y.charCodeAt()^(p=k+p).charCodeAt(i)))=>F(a)>F(b))
```

JavaScript is long at charcoding...

For [0,65536) +1e4 all be 5 digits so can be compared like string

```js
Q=
k=>p=>p.sort((a,b,F=x=>[...x].map((y,i)=>1e9|y.charCodeAt()^(p=k+p).charCodeAt(i)))=>F(a)>F(b))
;
console.log(Q("912")(["abcde", "hello", "test", "honk"]));
console.log(Q("taco")(["this", "is", "a", "taco", "test"]));
console.log(Q("thisisalongkey")(["who", "what", "when"]));
console.log(Q("3")(["who", "what", "when"]));
```

Comment: Threoiy I can use `k+=k` instead of `p=k+p` but too many memory using with the small test case

Answer (score 2):

## [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl), <s>101</s> <s>100</s> 94 bytes

*-6 bytes thanks to Ourous!*

```
import StdEnv
? =toInt
s k=let%s=[b bitxor?a\\a<-s&b<-[?c\\_<-s,c<-k]];@a b= %b> %a in sortBy@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ncy7DoIwFIDh3ac4C3aByVEqxOhA4sbYNua0VG3oxdB64eWtOLh9//Irq9FnF4aH1eDQ@GzcPUwJ@jQc/XPVAE2h82kVYaRWpyJSJkGa9A5Tg5xjXcW1rCvWKM7PS5SqrkYhti2CpFDIHRQIxkNcpvu5zX3C5U4hAiMbIoAx8roFIkr4AdNf2hMh8kddLF5jrrpTPswenVHxCw) Example usage: `s ['3'] [['who'], ['what'], ['when']]`.

#### Ungolfed:

```
import StdEnv
sort key list = 
   let
      f string = [(toInt a) bitxor (toInt b) \\ a<-string & b<-flatten(repeat key)]
      comp a b = f a <= f b
   in sortBy comp list
```

Comment: `? =toInt` and using `?` instead saves 2 bytes, and using a flipped greater-than instead of less-or-equals saves another one.

Comment: Even better, saves 6 bytes: [TIO](https://tio.run/##Ncy7DoIwFIDh3ac4C3aByVEqxOhA4sbYNua0VG3oxdB64eWtOLh9//Irq9FnF4aH1eDQ@GzcPUwJ@jQc/XPVAE2h82kVYaRWpyJSJkGa9A5Tg5xjXcW1rCvWKM7PS5SqrkYhti2CpFDIHRQIxkNcpvu5zX3C5U4hAiMbIoAx8roFIkr4AdNf2hMh8kddLF5jrrpTPswenVHxCw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 24 bytes

```
O╗⌠;O;l;╜@αH♀^♂cΣ@k⌡MS♂N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/9//0dTpj3oWWPtb51g/mjrH4dxGj0czG@IezWxKPrfYIftRz0LfYCDH7///aKXEpOSUVCUdBaWM1JycfBCjJLW4BCyQn5etFMulZGlopAQA)

Explanation:

```
O╗⌠;O;l;╜@αH♀^♂cΣ@k⌡MS♂N
O╗                        store ordinals of key in register 0
  ⌠;O;l;╜@αH♀^♂cΣ@k⌡M     for each string in array:
   ;O                       make a copy, ordinals
     ;l;                    make a copy of ordinals, length, copy length
        ╜@αH                list from register 0, cycled to length of string
            ♀^              pairwise XOR
              ♂cΣ           convert from ordinals and concatenate
                 @k         swap and nest (output: [[a XOR key, a] for a in array])
                     S♂N  sort, take last element (original string)
```

Comment: @ATaco No it doesn't. Try it with `["who", "what", "when"]` and `"thisisalongkey"`

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing That was posted before a patch to Actually on TIO.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2,  <s>204 140 134</s>  126 bytes

*Thanks to @Mr. Xcoder for saving 64 bytes, thanks to @ovs for saving six bytes, and thanks to @Dennis for saving eight bytes!*

```python
lambda k,l:[x(k,s)for s in sorted(x(k,s)for s in l)]
x=lambda k,s:''.join(chr(ord(v)^ord(k[i%len(k)]))for i,v in enumerate(s))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fcvBCsIwDAbgu09RCmILQ1BPCj7JnFC3zNbWRNq46dNP14GgBy9J@PN/tydbwvXQ7g9DMNdTY4Qvwq58KF8k3VIUSTgUiSJDo37SoKvZY/9habdYLC/kUNU2KoqN6vRxXL508wCovK501q7oRg94v0I0DCppPdyiQxatktvVWhailOZUN/C@pIUQaDwYEueA0MtKzz6ETU3ZsHVpbEzTZDT9JvyF3l2XTCA8e3hm3ttc7a3haQN@kc2f1vAC)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 37 bytes

```
{@^b.sort(*.comb Z~^(|$^a.comb xx*))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7dCoJAEIXve4pDRJRUUEFQmPQO3SUKo62u@LOxu1Bi9uo2sdRFw8zAOecbmJvQ1W6oW0wzHIfuFCcro7SdeatU1Qkur3j2nMTk1OPhzef9kCkNf7/egJL0KiBFVSlYYSykaspgMQKXbyllVxYG3AQnGfrlHBWGKtXkpWhxl4qHLC/RfJntn41lgHDC@ALeibSmNkIHQy3GZ/66aHL4zg@jAPfCSnzoA/wug7tzMfpgjH54Aw)

`$^a` and `@^b` are the key and array arguments to the function, respectively.  `@^b.sort(...)` simply sorts the input array according to the predicate function it is given.  That function takes a single argument, so `sort` will pass it each element in turn and treat the return value as a key for that element, sorting the list by the keys of the elements.

The sorting function is `*.comb Z~^ (|$^a.comb xx *)`.  `*` is the single string argument to the function.  `*.comb` is a list of the individual characters of the string.  `|$^a.comb xx *` is a list of the characters in the xor sorting key, replicated infinitely.  Those two lists are zipped together (`Z`) using the stringwise xor operator (`~^`).  Since the sorting predicate returns a sort key which is a list, `sort` orders two elements by comparing the first elements of the returned lists, then the second elements if the first elements are the same, et cetera.

Comment: `{sort *.comb »~^»$^a.comb,@^b}`

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>132</s> <s>128</s> 126 bytes

```c
char*k;g(a,b,i,r)char**a,**b;{r=k[i%strlen(k)];(r^(i[*a]?:-1))-(r^(i[*b]?:-2))?:g(a,b,i+1);}f(c,v)int*v;{k=*v;qsort(v,c,8,g);}
```

Takes an argument count and a pointer to a string array (the key, followed by the strings to be sorted) and modifies the string array in-place.

The code is highly non-portable and requires 64-bit pointers, gcc, and glibc.

*Thanks to @ceilingcat for golfing off 2 bytes!*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVHBTsMwDD23X2EFISVtBnRcgG7wIVWRsixdQ0sDTSiCqd8@nGTAuJFDHD@/Z1svcrGT8nCQrRizrtxRwTdc85EFIBM8yzblflx3lT63buzVQDtWl3R8pLrKRP1wtygYWxzzjc@XjD3cHRvlBSvnhko@MT24bCr33RrvV2tGRycu@Q3fIeNwpgfZv20VrKzbanPR3qcpCuBZ6IGydJ8mfh/InLLOVnVVLG9qWKcJFpI9kNtiSTicHCI2cqsQI63qe@MfXhoAM3QEYOZR6oQ0f7TEtdp6YrxF0EZS7PErRaK2ojfDrlMfvv7emhiEi1EN5HStH@n133Xhn9K5TNOkMSPQYIeGNVyVGFZg9acyDQR/4PI7jX4hI89ZNMubiv8ogxLzaGuG0IRQtFfXfkzy3upeAfWlKs@9qGah0HhMct9nOiI/Kz1hl6LEsApj8BVGJ8nLiKMbSs4tkCitno79Xt6cpYRgkszpfPgC)

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5, <s>80 + 3 (`anl`) = 83</s>, 67 bytes

```
sub{$,=shift;sub X{$_^substr$,x y///c,0,y///c};map X,sort map X,@_}
```

[try it online](https://tio.run/##dY5NDoIwEIX3nGLSdAFJDf7EhTYYFh7CxCipWIQIlLRDlBjPjoWaqAtn0fc6873JNFKXy741ErYCxXq9batGau5VHdAMIuhNe3pQFpm8yJDbD@weNDlaY1BTdocuDMOUTdmoT16JBnbMKI3gbJw8e@41uqjRd8v9Pc0mGz@mSXAIAsiU9sDWnqxmc8Lgq4g4pWdpeySXZakGg9Lg2FD1lRzYO4kiVT9RgnlhBs69Yow6yK34RC1YGFGq@nKV3TC/5cqJQKey/uCL3wvhL869/gU)

Comment: This repeats the key 9 times, which isn’t enough in general. For example, the output will be wrong for `9`; `abcdeabcde abcdeabcdz` (should give `abcdeabcdz abcdeabcde`)

Comment: @Lynn, fixed adding 3 bytes

Comment: could save 16 bytes using subs

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5, 88 bytes

```
sub{[map@$_[0],sort{@$a[1]cmp@$b[1]}map[$_,substr$_^($_[0]x length),0,length],@{$_[1]}]}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##fY6xbsMgEIZ3PwVCDLZEpaRVh8ZK5SFvgah1dnGwgsECrDSy8uzuxXRwlt4Ap/@@j2NU3rwvU1DkBBEOh9M0jMqX2XAjrCNHsoSpmcUAY8VqsZM8OB/nioHYy3bAsMHmjmPBao5oiJ7VX/nK/hCj7Dnqgu946iSvZhyhIe9LmY2@tzFPG3PWvXzmuKQoCtI5nxEsQT/2r5STTQkKTfutMKRaGeMeTVQhroGzFyol/3MjtO5Jxkj34UGmE1Y5UemRjYxkH8A4e76oGwKCXvUKXjXEdCu7Ed6e/0n@Ecps@QU).

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 80 bytes

```
#(sort-by(fn[s](apply str(apply map bit-xor(for[i[(cycle %)s]](map int i)))))%2)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), <s>285</s> 284 bytes

```
{for(;z++<128;){o[sprintf("%c",z)]=z}split(substr($0,0,index($0,FS)),k,"");$1="";split($0,w);for(q in w){split(w[q],l,"");d="";for(;i++<length(l);){d=d sprintf("%c",xor(o[k[(i-1)%(length(k)-1)+1]],o[l[i]]))}a[q]=d;i=0}asort(a,b);for(j in b){for(i in a){printf(a[i]==b[j])?w[i]FS:""}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY9BbsMgEEWvglAiMTKR7KzaUtRdLpAlYoGDUxOQSQyRI1uc3cV2Nt39mXkz/48a7DxPV98TNhbFd3X8YDB5Ee696eKV4P0F0xEkH1O4OxNJeNYh9mRX0pKaTjevRZ7OANRSjIHtKo4x29g8GYAttx/IdGiAaesP4iGpW3G90Ku7ye6u6X5jSxzkDJpr9C/FK1NeWEHMoYI9ebMWclVUUlIvnDBSAiSV73PNDC@TCr6PRNF6y3FbctSw/msWrWB6e6i8zHktbhJ@hqxP5y@MU0rz/FkdkaovukFt45xHsQkRtb6zfw)

Accepts input in the form of `key word word ...` eg `912 abcde hello test honk`

Outputs sorted words space separated

Slightly more readable

```
{
  for (; z++ < 128;) {
    o[sprintf("%c", z)] = z
  }
  split(substr($0, 0, index($0, FS)), k, "");
  $1 = "";
  split($0, w);
  for (q in w) {
    split(w[q], l, "");
    d = "";
    for (; i++ < length(l);) {
      d = d sprintf("%c", xor(o[k[(i - 1) % (length(k) - 1) + 1]], o[l[i]]))
    }
    a[q] = d;
    i = 0;
  }
  asort(a, b);
  for (j in b) {
    for (i in a) {
      printf(a[i] == b[j]) ? w[i] FS : ""
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Factor, 85

```
[ [ dup length rot <array> concat [ bitxor ] 2map ] with
[ dup bi* <=> ] curry sort ]
```

First try, I'll see if I can golf it further tomorrow.

I accept suggestions ;)

Answer (score 0):

### **Dyalog APL, 34 bytes**

Dfn, uses ⎕ml 3

```
{⍵[⍋⊃82⎕dr¨⊃≠/11⎕dr¨¨⍵((⍴¨⍵)⍴⊂⍺)]}
```