# Find the program that prints this integer sequence (Cops' thread)

Tags: number, sequence, cops-and-robbers

**This is the cops' thread. The robbers' thread goes [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77420/find-the-program-that-prints-this-integer-sequence-robber-thread).**

The last [cops-and-robbers](/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) thread was already [4 months ago](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/67756/printing-ascending-ascii-cops).

### The cop's task

- The cop's task is to write a program/function that takes a positive (or non-negative) integer and outputs/returns another integer.
- **The cop must state it if the program is intolerant towards zero.**
- The cop will provide at least **2** sample inputs/outputs.
- For example, if I have decided to write the [Fibonacci sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number), I would write this in my answer:

```
a(0) returns 0
a(3) returns 2
```

- The number of examples is up to the cop's discretion.
- However, the sequence must actually exist in [the On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences®](http://oeis.org/), so no pseudo-random number generator for you. `:(`
- **The cop can hide as many characters as is so wished.**
- For example, if my program is:

---

```
function a(n)
    if n>2 then
        return n
    else
        return a(n-1) + a(n-2)
    end
end
```

---

- Then I would hide these characters as I want:

---

```
function a(n)
    if ### then
        ########
    else
        ######################
    end
end
```

---

### The robber's task

- is obviously to find the original source code.
- **However, any proposed source code that produces the same set of output also counts as valid, as long as it is also found in OEIS.**

---

### Tips for the cops

- <s>The search function in the OEIS only works for consecutive terms, so if you want to hide your sequence, then just leave a hole anywhere.</s>
- Apparently there is no way to hide the sequence. Put this in mind when you choose the sequence.

---

Your score is the number of bytes in your code.

The winner will be the submission with the lowest score that hasn't been cracked in 7 days.

Only submissions that are posted in 2016 April are eligible for the win. Submissions that are posted later than this are welcome, but cannot win.

In order to claim the win you need to reveal the full code and the OEIS sequence (after 7 days).

Your post should be formatted like this (NN is the number of characters):

---

## Lua, 98 bytes

Output:

```
a(0) returns 0
a(3) returns 2
```

Code (`#` marks unrevealed characters):

```
function a(n)
    if ### then
        ########
    else
        ######################
    end
end
```

---

If the code is cracked, insert `[Cracked](link to cracker)` in the header.
If the submission is safe, insert "Safe" in the header and reveal the full code in your answer. Only answers that have revealed the full code will be eligible for the win.

Comment: Just to clarify: if I post a cop which specifies `a(0) = 1, a(1)= 1` with the Fibonacci sequence in mind, and a robber posts a crack which outputs the constant `1` sequence (i.e. not what I had in mind), then does this count as cracked?

Comment: Also, OEIS search can have blanks with `_`, fyi

Comment: Also "the parts of the code not related to the number generation must be revealed" seems a bit confusing to me. Suppose I posted an answer in Brainfuck - which parts would that be?

Comment: In your example you choose to reveal the spaces. Does that mean that you could just add as many spaces as you need in your submission to not reveal anything important?

Comment: @Sp3000 Re "OEIS search can have blanks": Then how would I hide the sequence?

Comment: @user81655 Yes, but that would count towards the byte count.

Comment: @Sp3000 Re "a robber posts a crack which outputs the constant 1 sequence": "**However, any proposed source code that produces the same set of output also counts as valid (you are encouraged to reproduce an actual sequence in the OEIS).**"

Comment: @Sp3000 Re "`a(0) = 1, a(1)= 1` with the Fibonacci sequence in mind": `a(0)=0`.

Comment: So if I have, say, 31 characters, do I have to show six or seven of them?

Comment: It may be too late to change, but allowing sequences that are multiples of an OEIS sequence, and/or only include every nth term would have made this challenge *much* better.  *sandbox, hint, hint*

Comment: I don't think that is necessary.

Comment: Can I, for example, pick the Fibonacci sequence and provide only `a(1000)`? (which is part of the sequence, but too large to be searchable on OEIS)

Comment: I'd say the values have to actually be searchable on OEIS, so that it can easily be verified that the values are correct for the chosen sequence.

Comment: "Intolerant towards zero" makes no sense. What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: @feersum I would believe it means whether or not the program outputs the sequence starting with 0 or 1, but I'd also like clarification.

Comment: In your example program I think you meant `n<2`

Comment: Can cops post more than one answer?

Comment: I don't understand... What is a "Safe" answer ?

Comment: @FliiFe An answer that doesn't get cracked in a week.

Comment: @KennyLau After a week, an answer cannot be cracked anymore, can it ?

Comment: Nope, it cannot.

Answer (score 11):

## Vim, 36 keystrokes -- Safe!

```
i****<esc>:let @q="^*i****$**@***"<cr><n>@qbD
```

(Note: `<n>` is where you type your input)

Here is the code unrelated to number generation:

```
          :let @q="              "<cr><n>@qbD
```

Meaning I am revealing 5 out of 19 characters.

`<n>` is the input. Here are some sample outputs:

```
1@q:    1
2@q:    3
6@q:    18
```

## Answer

This code prints The Lucas Numbers ([A000032](https://oeis.org/A000032)), which are just like The Fibonnaci Sequence, except that it starts on `2, 1` instead of `1, 1`. Here are the first 15 numbers:

```
2, 1, 3, 4, 7, 11, 18, 29, 47, 76, 123, 199, 322, 521, 843
```

Here's the revealed code:

```
i2 1 <esc>:let @q="^diwwyw$pb@-<c-v><c-a>"<cr><n>@qbD
```

Explanation:

```
i2 1 <esc>                          "Insert the starting numbers
          :let @q="....."<cr>       "Define the macro 'Q'
```

Explanation of the macro:

```
^                      "Move to the first non-whitespace character on the line.
 diw                   "(d)elete (i)nner (w)ord. This is different then 'dw' because it doesn't grab the space. 
                      "It also throws people off since 'i' is usually used for inserting text.
    wyw$               "Move to the next number, yank it then move to the end of the line 
        pb             "(p)aste the yanked text and move (b)ack
          @-     <c-a> "@- is the register holding the word we deleted. Increment the current number that many times.
            <c-v>      "Since we're adding <c-a> this from the command line, we need to type it as a literal.
```

Now, we just need to remove the second number, since the first number is the lucas number we want. So we do

```
b   "move (b)ack
 D  "(D)elete to the end of the line.
```

Also, if I'm not mistaken, this is the first safe submission! That's kinda cool.

Comment: I know the sequence, I think. I just don't know how to turn it into Vim keystrokes.

Comment: Is the output just the number or the entire line?

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI After hitting `bD` at the end, the output is just the one number and some extra whitespace.

Comment: I got the sequence right!

Answer (score 8):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes, safe

Last one for today :p. Output:

```
a(0) = 9
a(5) = 4
a(10) = 89
```

Code:

```
___m_
```

Obfuscated characters are indicated with `_`. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/)-link. Uses **CP-1252** encoding.

---

#### Solution:

```
žhžm‡
```

Explanation:

```
žh       # Short for [0-9].
  žm     # Short for [9-0].
    ‡    # Translate.
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=xb5oxb5t4oCh&input=MA) or [Try for all test cases!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=W0nFvUQiYSjDvykgPSAic8W-aMW-beKAocKrLA&input=MAo1CjEw).

Comment: I know the sequence, just not how to generate it in so few bytes...

Comment: @LegionMammal978 Yes, I think that is going to be the hardest part of this one.

Comment: I can get it in 5 bytes with `g°<¹-` but I can't figure out any way to use `m` at this size! D:

Comment: @user81655 Yes, that was the alternative solution :).

Answer (score 6):

## [Element](https://github.com/PhiNotPi/Element), 7 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77439/48934)

Output:

```
a(3) = 111
a(7) = 1111111
```

The `#` are hidden characters, and they are all printable ASCII.  I think this one is actually reasonably difficult (for only having 5 missing characters).

```
###,##}
```

For convenience, here's the [Try It Online](http://element.tryitonline.net/) and [Esolang wiki](https://esolangs.org/wiki/element) pages.

---

My original program was:

> `` _'[,$`} ``

The trick is that

> `]` and `}` are functionally identical (both translate to `}` in Perl).  Also, I used `,$` to produce a `1` as an additional layer of confusion, although it is possible to ignore the `,` completely by doing `,1` instead.

Comment: (I know I shouldn't ask this, but) are you sure that it is correct? In particular, `}` instead of `]`?

Comment: @KennyLau The `}` is correct, and my program (as far as I know) works in every version of Element.

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77439/48934)

Comment: I think the formatting is wrong in your original code?

Comment: @EasterlyIrk It is.  If you know how to fix it, be my guest.

Comment: @PhiNotPi fixedish.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jolf](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Jolf), 5 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77422/31957)

Output:

```
a(2) = 8
a(10) = 4738245926336
```

All of it is crucial, and I have shown 1 of 5.

```
####x
```

Original code:

```
mPm$x
mP     cube
  m$   catalan number
    x  input
```

[Try it online!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=bVBtJHg&input=MTA)

Comment: [Cracked!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77422/48934)

Comment: For anyone interested, it's this sequence: https://oeis.org/A033536

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES7), 10 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77756/46855)

#### Output

```
f(0) -> 1
f(1) -> -1
```

#### Code

```
t=>~t##**#
```

**Test it in Firefox nightly.** The code is an anonymous function. This will probably be easy since there's only three characters hidden, but at least it's short! :P

---

My original code was:

> `t=>~top**t`

but after brute-forcing my own code for a solution, I soon realised

> `t=>~t.x**t` (where `x` can be any variable name character)

could also be used. This works because

> in the original ES7 exponentiation operator spec, the operator had lower precedence than unary operators (unlike conventional mathematics and most other languages). `~` performs a bitwise NOT on `t.x` (`undefined`) or `top` (`Object`) which casts them to a 32-bit signed integer (uncastables like these become `0`) before doing the NOT (so `0` becomes `-1`). I looked into further into this, and very recently, the spec has changed to disallow ambiguous references like this (not good for future golfing D: ), however most ES7 engines haven't updated to the latest version of the spec yet.

Comment: @insertusernamehere It seems to think it contains an illegal expression. It does work in Firefox nightly though. I guess they implement the ES7 spec differently.

Comment: I just got Firefox nightly, and I must complain that this _does not work_ there. 32-bit windows from [here](https://nightly.mozilla.org/)

Comment: Assuming `**` is equivalent to `Math.pow`, I have done some of my own testing, and even run a brute force. This is quite hard to crack!

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ My Firefox nightly is up to date as of yesterday. I'm using OS X but I'm quite sure it will work in Windows also. [Traceur](http://google.github.io/traceur-compiler/demo/repl.html#%2F%2F%20Options%3A%20--annotations%20--array-comprehension%20--async-functions%20--async-generators%20--comment-callback%20--debug-names%20--exponentiation%20--for-on%20--generator-comprehension%20--member-variables%20--referrer%20--require%20--script%20--source-root%20--spread-properties%20--types%20%0A%0At%3D%3E~t%23%23**%23) with appropriate ES7 options enabled transpiles it correctly too.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Just tried it in 32-bit Windows from your link and it works also. I'm surprised your brute force search couldn't crack it. I actually just realised there's many solutions to this! D:

Comment: @user81655 _Weird_. I've been assuming the problem is of the form `t=>~t<op><data>**<data>`, where `<op>` is any unary operator and `<data>` is any of `0123456789t`.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Well who knows, *anything* could be under the hashes... :P

Comment: [Cracked?](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77756/41859)

Comment: In my cellphone appear above, some yellow (giallo) rectangles voids

Answer (score 4):

### 05AB1E, 4 bytes ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77447/34388))

Sample output :

```
a(5) = 51
a(8) = 257
```

And for the code :

```
###^
```

I revealed the last one. Should be easy enough though, I had quite a hard time finding a sequence :(

All hidden characters are printable.

Comment: [Cracked!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77447/34388) :)

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](http://matl.tryitonline.net), 5 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77479/36398)

Hidden characters are indicated by `%`.

```
%5%*%
```

Output:

```
a(1) = 3
a(2) = 6
a(4) = 12
```

Input `0` is valid.

---

Original code:

```
35B*s
```

that is,

```
35    % push number 35
B     % convert to binary: array [1 0 0 0 1 1]
*     % multiply element-wise by implicit input n: gives [n 0 0 0 n n]
s     % sum of array: gives 3*n
```

Comment: Hmmm, the five in code is very annoying!

Comment: Technically this could be brute-forced by a program... but I won't do that.

Comment: [cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77479/24877)

Answer (score 4):

## SWIFT, 55 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77420/find-the-program-that-prints-this-integer-sequence-robbers-thread/77765#77765)

```
func M(n:Int)->Int{
return(n*****) ?M(**n****):n***;
}
```

`*` marks a hidden character

Output:

```
M(30) -> 91
M(60) -> 91
M(90) -> 91
M(120)-> 110
M(150)-> 140
```

Function accepts `0`

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77765/47066)

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, 46 bytes, safe

Edit to add disclaimer/apology: This sequence starts with f[0], while the OEIS entry starts with f[1]. The values are the same.

Obfuscated code (`#` is any character):

```
->####or x##1###(#..##0#);x*=3;end;#.###ect:+}
```

Call like

```
->####or x##1###(#..##0#);x*=3;end;#.###ect:+}[3] (returns 39)
```

Output:

```
f[0] = 0
f[1] = 3
f[2] = 12
f[3] = 39
f[4] = 120
f[5] = 363
f[6] = 1092
f[7] = 3279
f[8] = 9840
f[9] = 29523
```

Solution:

> `f=->*x{for x[-1]in(0..x[0]);x*=3;end;x.inject:+}`

Sequence:

> http://oeis.org/A029858

Explanation:

> The minor trick here is that we declare the parameter as `*x` rather than `x`. This means that if you pass in `2`, `x` is set to `[2]`...at first. The *major* trick exploits bizarre, and justly obscure, Ruby syntax where you can set the iterator in a for loop to any valid left hand side of an assignment expression, instead of an iterator variable like `i`. So this loops through from 0 to (in this example) 2, assigning each number to `x[-1]`, meaning it overwrites the last value of x. Then the loop body `x*=3`, further mutates x by concatenating it to itself 3 times. So first x becomes `[0]`, then `[0,0,0]`. On the next loop it becomes `[0,0,1]`, then `[0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1]`. Finally we pass in 2 and it becomes `[0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,2]`, then `[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2]`. We then sum the result using the `inject` method, which reduces the array by applying `+` (the passed in method) to each element in turn. If we consider how each iteration changes the sum, we see that we effectively add 1 (by overwriting the last element with an element one higher), then multiply by 3. Since `3*(n+1) = 3*n + 3`, this implements Alexandre Wajnberg's recurrence relation for the sequence as described on the page.

Comment: I really like your cops here, this one particularly.  Well done.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77444/48934)

Output:

```
a(9) = 165
a(10) = 220
```

Hidden code:

```
##O
```

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=IyNP&input=NQ) might come in handy.

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77444/48934)

Answer (score 3):

## [Hexagony](http://github.com/mbuettner/hexagony), 7 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77446/34388)

Output:

```
a(1) = 2
a(2) = 4
```

Hidden code:

```
?#####@
```

Or alternatively:

```
 ? #
# # #
 # @
```

[Try it online](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/) might come in handy.

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77446/8478)

Comment: Uhhh wait, does your code work for input `0`?

Comment: @MartinBüttner Oh, it doesn't, my bad. Your solution was the right one though.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 41 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77466/41859)

Yeah, finally another Cops and Robbers challenge. Hope I didn't make it to easy.

**Output**

```
a(5)   = 0
a(15)  = 1
a(35)  = 0
a(36)  = 1
a(45)  = 1
```

**Source**

```
____________________$argv[1]____________;
####################        ############
```

**Notes**

- It's a full program, not a function.
- Reads the input from command line (obviously).
- [Does not contain any PHP opening tag](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7098/is-the-php-opening-tag-mandatory-in-byte-count).

---

**Cracked**

I obviously made it to easy and provided not enough examples. The sequence I had in mind was [A010054](https://oeis.org/A010054):

> a(n) = 1 if n is a triangular number else 0.

Here's my original source code:

> `echo(int)($r=sqrt(8*$argv[1]+1))==$r?1:0;`

It tests whether the input is a *triangular number* and outputs `1` or `0` accordingly.

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77466)

Answer (score 3):

### [Pyke](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk), 15 bytes, SAFE

Output

```
a(2) = 21
a(15) = 17
```

Revealed code:

```
#R#D######+##)#
```

Solution:

> OEIS [A038822](https://oeis.org/A038822)
>
> `wR}DSR_Q*L+#P)l`
>
>  I used a couple of red herrings here by using `wR}` to generate the number 100 and revealing the character `R` which is normally used to rotate the stack. I also used `#P)l` instead of the more simple `mPs` to count the number of primes in the sequence.

Comment: The sequence in question starts from n=1 not n=0 by the way

Comment: I thought it was that sequence, except it starts at n=0 and not n=1 as you've stated.

Answer (score 3):

## C, 71 bytes [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77549/52554)

```
############
#####
main(){
 scanf("%d",##);
 ###6#;
 printf("%d",##);
}
```

Output:

```
a(1) = 0   a(2) = 0   a(5) = 1
a(6) = 1   a(7) = 1   a(9) = 2
```

This works with gcc, and is a full program. It accepts 0 as input.

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77549/30688)

Comment: Well, I should've revealed more characters. I posted a different one, and I tried to avoid function calls. http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77583/52554

Answer (score 3):

## Jolf, 11 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77420/find-the-program-that-prints-this-integer-sequence-robbers-thread/77491#77491) , [A011551](https://oeis.org/A011551)

```
c*______x__

c*mf^+91x~P
```

Original code:

```
c*^c"10"x~P
```

Examples:

```
0 -> 1

12 -> 1618033988749
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77491/34388).

Comment: @Adnan Good job, though different from mine. And you couldn't figure out first op. :P

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't figure out what it does :p

Comment: @Adnan it was a cast to int function, misused as a floor one.

Answer (score 3):

## Java, 479 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77497/41505)

Outputs:

```
a(10) = 81
a(20) = 35890
```

(Inputs are provided via command line arguments)

Code (`#` marks hidden characters):

```
import java.util.*;
public class A{

    public static int#########
    public boolean###########

    static A a = new A();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int input = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        LinkedList<Integer> l = new LinkedList<>();
        l.add(1);
        l.add(0);
        l.add(0);

        for(int ix = 0; ################if(##>##{
            ###########d#
            #######+##p##########+##########(#######
        }

        System.out.println(#########################
            ###(A.#############(#5#####)));
    }
}
```

The program starts at index 0.

(Note that SE replaces all of the `\t` indents with 4 spaces, bringing the byte total to 569. Click [here](https://goo.gl/4yS0Ff) to see the program with `\t` indents instead of space indents.)

Original code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class A{
    public static interface B{
    public boolean C(int i);} 
    
    static A a = new A();
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int input = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        
        LinkedList<Integer> l = new LinkedList<>();
        l.add(1);
        l.add(0);
        l.add(0);
        
        for(int ix = 0; ix<input; ix++)cif(i->  {
            return l.add(
            l.pop()+l.peekFirst()+l.peekLast());});{    
        }
        
        System.out.println(l.get(1));}static boolean 
            cif(A.B b5){return (b5.C((0)));
    }
}
```

(Same code, but formatted normally):

```
import java.util.*;

public class A {
    public static interface B { //functional interface for lambda expression
        public boolean C(int i); //void would have given it away
    }

    static A a = new A(); //distraction

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int input = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);//Input

        LinkedList<Integer> l = new LinkedList<>();
        l.add(1);//Set up list
        l.add(0);
        l.add(0);

        for (int ix = 0; ix < input; ix++)
            cif(i -> { //Fake if statement is really a lambda expression
                return l.add(l.pop() + l.peekFirst() + l.peekLast());
            });
        { //Distraction
        }

        System.out.println(l.get(1));//Output
    }

    static boolean cif(A.B b5) { //Used to pass in lambda expression.
                  //The A. and b5 were both distractions
        return (b5.C((0)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm, how do you come to a byte count of 488? I count 545 from `i` to `}`?  
And please specify 0-tolerance.

Comment: Aren't your examples `a(9)` and `a(19)` or `a(8)` and `a(18)`, according to which version of it on OEIS you took?

Comment: @BjörnKautler I'll post a link to the byte counter when I get home. What do you mean by 0-tolerance? The first value is a(1) = 0

Comment: From the OP:
"The cop's task is to write a program/function that takes a positive (or non-negative) integer and outputs/returns another integer.
The cop must state it if the program is intolerant towards zero." So I guess you take the input 1 as 0 and this also explains the shift in position, according to the OEIS sequence.

Comment: @BjörnKautler OK, thanks. The program doesn't crash if 0 is entered but the sequence starts at index 1, so I guess it's zero-intolerant.

Comment: Are you sure? The only matching sequences I found on OEIS that match your samples start at 0 and for one the results would be `a(9)` and `a(19)`, for the other `a(8)` and `a(18)`

Comment: @BjörnKautler OEIS is 0-indexed? I'll change it then (in about an hour). Thanks

Comment: Depends on the sequence. The one you most probably used says `with a(0)=a(1)=0, a(2)=1` and also specifies the `offset` to be `0`, which means the first value in the shown numbers is the 0-value. You can also click on the `list` link after the numbers and you get a list with n-to-a(n) mapping.

Comment: @BjörnKautler I'm not all that familiar with OEIS so that's good to know. I need to test it before I change this post, but to make the code 0-indexed, "int ix = 1" should become "int ix = 0"

Comment: Me neither. Just learned about OEIS some minutes ago when I recognized this challenge :-)

Comment: @BjörnKautler It seems that SE replaces all tab indents with space indents, upping the byte count. I added a note to clarify the byte situation. Also, I fixed the 0-indexing. Have fun :)

Comment: Ah, tabs-vs-4spaces makes sense. And the newlines are also counted as 1 just as in the example, I see. :-) Thanks for clarification. One more question. I almost have it cracked, just a(0) and a(1) are wrong for me, all others are correct. You are sure the first two are calculated correctly by your code, aren't you? :-)

Comment: @BjörnKautler I double checked, and they are. Mind if I move the discussion to chat?

Comment: No need, it is [cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77497/52921). :-)

Comment: @BjörnKautler Was not expecting that so quickly (or so differently), given that the original had no if statement, and had a second method.

Comment: Or a ternary operator. :-D Yeah, I was pretty sure the original code is differently, but also didn't imagine that much. I didn't really expect an interface, an additional method or a lambda here. But the better for me, there was so much room, that I was able to fit in my code and comment out your revealed characters. :-D Though yours will not get an OutOfMemoryError, mine will if you give it a big enough n, as I continuously build up the ArrayList. :-)

Comment: That was pretty funny, I should more often solve those :-D

Answer (score 3):

## Octave, 34 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77532/31516)

```
@(m)(m###m#####m##)&isprime(#)####
```

Outputs:

```
ans(1) = 0
ans(6) = 5
ans(7) = 10
ans(8) = 15
```

The sequence starts at `ans(1)` in OEIS.

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77532/30688)

Answer (score 3):

## MATL, 9 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77494/42892)

Code:

```
3#2###*##
```

Output:

```
a(1)  = 3
a(2)  = 6
a(4)  = 12
a(12) = 37
```

`a(0)` is valid.

---

#### Cracked

Original sequence:
[A059563](https://oeis.org/A059563)

Original code:

```
3L2^Ze*sk
3L          % Push [1 -1j] from the clipboard
  2^        % square
    Ze      % exp
      *     % times input
       s    % sum
        k   % floor
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77494/34388).

Answer (score 3):

### Pyth, 70 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77530/34388)

```
DhbI|qb"#"qb"#"R!1Iqb"#"#####+""s####2###;##lY+Q1Ih+""Z#####)=Z+Z1;@YQ
```

`#` are the hidden characters

Has been cracked, so here is the versionn without hidden chars :

```
DhbI|qb"4"qb"0"R!1Iqb"1"R!0Rh+""sm^sd2cb1;W<lY+Q1Ih+""Z=Y+YZ)=Z+Z1;@YQ
```

Sample outputs :

```
a(2) -> 10
a(4) -> 19
```

<s>Good luck to find this on OEIS, I personally failed to find it from those examples (even tho the sequence is quite easy to spot.)</s>

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77530/34388).

Answer (score 3):

### Lua, 45 Bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77763/41019)

A small hint:

```
a(0) will make the program crash :)
```

#### Output

```
a(1)=>0
a(2)=>1
```

#### Code

Uses `#` to hide the code :).

```
a=function(n)#####n###### and #or ########end
```

I was using the OEIS [A007814](http://oeis.org/A007814), with the following code:

```
a=function(n)return n%2>0 and 0or 1+a(n/2)end
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77763/48934).

Comment: @KennyLau Well done, I've added the OEIS I was thinking to and the intended code, I should have added at least one more output to prevent this to happen :p

Answer (score 3):

## C, 82 bytes, safe

```
####=############
main(i){scanf("%d",##);
for(i=1;i++/4<#;)##=2;
printf("%d",##);}
```

Works with gcc, and it is a full program, which reads its input from stdin and prints its output to stdout. Here the sequence is <s>A004526, floor(n/2)</s>.

```
a(0) = 0    a(1) = 0    a(2) = 1
a(3) = 1    a(4) = 2    a(5) = 2
a(6) = 3    a(7) = 3    a(8) = 4
```

**Solution:**

```
a;*b=(char*)&a+1;
main(i){scanf("%d",&a);
for(i=1;i++/4<2;)a*=2;
printf("%d",*b);}
```

This works only on little endian machines, and only if the size of `char` is 1 byte. 
And only if the byte higher than the highest order byte of `a` has value 0. I think this is true for gcc since by default uninitialized global variables go into the bss segment, and initialized global variables go into the data segment (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721475/if-a-global-variable-is-initialized-to-0-will-it-go-to-bss).
 So only `a` goes into bss (the only other global variable `b` is initialized and thus goes into the data segment). If `a` is not at the end of bss, then the byte higher than the highest order byte of `a` is also in bss and thus has value 0.

Comment: Try making function calls now :)

Comment: I don't think you had to specify the sequence...

Comment: @FliiFe - Fixed :)

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 38 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77621/6828)

Obfuscated code (`#` can be any character):

```
->#{(s=#########).sum==#3333&&eval(s)}
```

Output:

Multiplies the input by 10 (A008592). Works for any integer, including 0. e.g.

```
->#{(s=#########).sum==#3333&&eval(s)}[3]  => 30
->#{(s=#########).sum==#3333&&eval(s)}[10] => 100
```

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77621/45268)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77680/34388)

Output:

```
a(0) = 0
a(1) = 0
a(2) = 1
a(3) = 1
a(4) = 1
a(5) = 1
a(6) = 1
a(7) = 1
a(8) = 1
a(9) = 1
a(10) = 0
a(11) = 0
```

Obfuscated code:

```
_____
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/)-link.

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77680/25180)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77708/34388)

Well then, I  think I'm addicted to CnR's... Obfuscated code (`_` indicates a wild card):

```
____
```

Sequence:

```
a(1) = 2
a(4) = 6720
```

The sequence in **OEIS** starts at a(1) = 2.

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/)-link

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77708/31849)

Answer (score 3):

### 05AB1E, 1 byte, Cracked

```
_
```

`_` denotes hidden code.

```
f(1) == 1
f(18) == 6
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78672/47066)

Answer (score 2):

## [Reng v.3.3](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/), 36 bytes. [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77438/31957), [A005449](http://oeis.org/A005449)

Output:

```
a(1) = 2
a(3) = 15
```

`#` denotes a gone character. There are no other `#`s in the program.

```
i#:#+##-##)####¡#~
##########!</div>
```

Alright this is the last one for a while. Other people need to answer >_>. A description of each character can be found in the source code, where all the ops are defined. A comment proceeds each operator.

Original code:

```
i>:1+(1-?v)v/a+¡n~
~^<$:$:$:>!</div>
```

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77438/48934)

Comment: What is the original sequence?

Comment: +1 for `</div>`, an HTML tag that strangely appeared in this code. I like finding out secrets like this. :-P

Comment: @zyabin101 XD Thanks! I put it there as a red herring.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jolf](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Jolf), 11 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77460/31541).

Output:

```
a(10) = 4
a(20) = 6
a(30) = 8
```

And the partially hidden code:

```
####xd###x#
```

Hint:

> When I looked through the sequences in order, I didn't go very far before finding this one.

The cracked version isn't quite the same as my original code. I'm not currently at my computer, so I don't have it exactly, but it was something like this:

> `l fzxd!m%xH`

(The only part I'm unsure about is the `!m`. It's whatever checks if a variable is zero.)

Comment: I found the sequence... Pity I don't know Jolf or javascript very well :(

Comment: @muddyfish, Same here...

Comment: Well, I guess it's time for the master to do it... may I?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ If everyone else is stumped – and it looks like they are – feel free.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77460/31957).

Comment: Interesting approach!

Answer (score 2):

## [Element](https://github.com/PhiNotPi/Element), 10 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77420/find-the-program-that-prints-this-integer-sequence-robbers-thread/77433#77433)

Output:

```
a(3) = 6561
a(4) = 4294967296
```

There's probably only a few ways to compute this sequence in Element.  I found a 9-char solution, but I figured this 10-char solution is actually more difficult.  The `#` are hidden characters.

```
#_####@^#`
```

For convenience, here's the [Try It Online](http://element.tryitonline.net/) and [Esolang wiki](https://esolangs.org/wiki/element) pages.

---

The original was

```
2_3:~2@^^`
```

Comment: Show one more byte.

Comment: @KennyLau I thought it was 1 out of 5?  It's 10 bytes and I'm showing 3.

Comment: Inputs and outputs don't count, so you have 8 bytes and you showed 1.

Comment: @KennyLau done.

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77433/48934)

Comment: @KennyLau nice.  (and slightly different than original)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 18 bytes

`#` marks unrevealed characters.

```
L?Jtb##5#m##S#2 #y
```

Outputs (starts from `1`):

```
1 -> 2
2 -> 3
3 -> 5
4 -> 7
```

[Online interpreter](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: Primes, no? If not...

Comment: If not... what?

Comment: then I have no idea

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77462)

I hope that this submission isn't as easy as my other ones :p. Outputs:

```
a(0) = 0
a(1) = 1
a(2) = 6
a(3) = 24
a(4) = 80
a(5) = 240
```

Obfuscated code:

```
####O
```

Contains some non-ASCII characters though, uses **CP-1252** encoding.

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/) might come in handy :p.

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77462)

Comment: Why do I feel like I've seen it before?

Comment: @KennyLau ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript ES6, 119 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77505/31957).

Output:

```
a(0) = 0
a(5) = 10000
```

Code:

```
x=>##=#=>[[[##x####r(###f#n###;#####n####h.##w###<1##].c####t.##pl##[####nc#######y([###(###(#]###)######`#######h####`
```

Returns an anonymous function.

Original sequence: [A016744](http://oeis.org/A016744).

Original code:

```
x=>{f=n=>[[[1,x] for(x of n)]];return Math.pow(x<<1,[].concat.apply([].concat.apply([],f(f(f([]))))).join``.length)}//`
```

I need to show more characters of obsfucated code next time :P

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77505/46855). I wasn't sure which sequence you were going for though, so I had to just choose the easiest one then ignore the rest of the characters. :(

Answer (score 2):

## Jolf, 13 bytes, safe!

Outputs:

```
a(5) = 40
a(8) = 128
```

Code:

```
#+~##~####xx#
```

[Interpreter](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/).

Revealed:

> OEIS A003600`γ+~iu~iZCzxxγ
> γ              γ = 
>          zx    range 1..x (input)
>        ZC      cumulutive sum
>      ~i        identity
>     u          sum of
>   ~i           identity
>  +         x   plus x
>             γ  out γ`

Comment: Ooh, Jolf. I'm gonna have a crack at this one. Please don't steal it, Kenny.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Any luck? :3

Comment: I might've had some of you didn't have undocumented functions everywhere :P. As it is, I've got two candidates for the sequence, and some idea of how to make them, but it's a pain in the butt :P

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I don't think this code uses any undocumented features.

Comment: But they still make reading the source hard. Anyway, I'm just complaining. Feel free to ignore me.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Consider yourself ignored ;)

Answer (score 2):

### [Pyke](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk), 6 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77478/32686)

```
###X#s
```

Output:

```
a(2) = 8
a(8) = 80
a(10) = 120
```

This doesn't work with N<1

Original solution:

> `hSmX$s`

Comment: Welp, I found an easier alternate to what I had

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77478)

Answer (score 2):

## Jolf, 16 bytes, safe!

Outputs:

```
a(0) = 0
a(4) = -2
a(51) = 26
```

Code:

```
#.‘###4#x##32#mA
```

Revealed:

> ```
> Sequence: A001057, the canonical enumeration of integers.
> *.‘01m4zx’m32xmA
>   ‘      ’        an array
>    0               0: 0
>     1              1: 1
>      m4zx          antisum of range 1..x (1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - ... - x)
>  .        m32x    get min(2, x) of that array
> *             mA  multiply that entry by the sign of x (implicit input); is zero when zero
> ```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77507/36398)

```
##s##
```

`#` indicates a hidden character.

Output:

```
a(4) = 8
a(6) = 144
```

The sequence starts at `a(1)`.

---

The original code was exactly as in [@Adnan's answer to robbers' thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77507/36398).

Comment: My first 05AB1E submission!

Comment: Wow! I'm glad to see this :)

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77507/34388).

Comment: @Adnan I thought it would last longer :-) Can sequences in OEIS be searched for specific terms?

Comment: @Adnan, Oh, there is. `_` is used for missing terms

Comment: Yes, although OEIS searches for the terms regardless of the starting position of a sequence. I made a script which also searches for the same starting index, so it would rule out other sequences.

Comment: @Adnan Could you share it ?

Comment: @FliiFe Probably gonna violate the copyright law, but [here you go](https://github.com/Adriandmen/OEISseeker).

Comment: @Adnan I think you could avoid copyright law infringement by first making a first search on oeis ([preformated](http://oeis.org/search?fmt=text&q=2,5,14,50,233)), and then let the script choose which one respects the indexes

Comment: @FliiFe Oh, that might be a better idea

Answer (score 2):

## J, 8 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77512/48934)

`#` marks unrevealed characters

```
(##-#)#.
```

([Online interpreter here.](http://tryj.tk/))

#### Output:

No, I'm not hiding anything by using a long sample. If the input is **0**, it outputs **0**, if the input is between **1** and **29**, it outputs **1**.

**The outputs for the negative inputs do not match with the actual sequence.**

```
   (##-#)#.0
0
   (##-#)#.1
1
   (##-#)#.2
1
   (##-#)#.3
1
   (##-#)#.4
1
   (##-#)#.5
1
   (##-#)#.6
1
   (##-#)#.7
1
   (##-#)#.8
1
   (##-#)#.9
1
   (##-#)#.10
1
   (##-#)#.11
1
   (##-#)#.12
1
   (##-#)#.13
1
   (##-#)#.14
1
   (##-#)#.15
1
   (##-#)#.16
1
   (##-#)#.17
1
   (##-#)#.18
1
   (##-#)#.19
1
   (##-#)#.20
1
   (##-#)#.21
1
   (##-#)#.22
1
   (##-#)#.23
1
   (##-#)#.24
1
   (##-#)#.25
1
   (##-#)#.26
1
   (##-#)#.27
1
   (##-#)#.28
1
   (##-#)#.29
1
```

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77512/25180)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 28  bytes [(Cracked)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77420/find-the-program-that-prints-this-integer-sequence-robbers-thread/77775#77775)

```
#D>D>D>D>*##*#D<*#+*#n#n#**#
```

a(1) = 1

a(2) = 8

a(3) = 42

Behaviour for zero is unspecified.

Cracked:

```
 DD>D>D>D>****rD<*6+*6n2n5**/
```

There is no need for an explanation I think as the crack was almost 100% spot on. The only difference is I used r to reverse stack instead of swapping top two elements.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77775/47066)

Answer (score 2):

### 05AB1E, 10 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77420/find-the-program-that-prints-this-integer-sequence-robbers-thread/79941#79941)

```
##3##1+*1+
```

0-indexed.

```
0 ==> 1
4 ==> 61
5 ==> 91
9 ==> 271
```

Original Program:

> `UX3*X1+*1+`

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/79941/47066)

Answer (score 2):

### [S.I.L.O.S](https://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/S.I.L.O.S), 37 bytes ([Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/96815/56721))

#### Code:

```
readIO
#=#
#+#
#*#
#*#
#+#
printInt i
```

`#`s are the hidden characters.

#### Output:

```
a(0) = 1
a(4) = 41
a(9) = 181
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/96815/47066)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://tryj.tk/), 7 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77431/48934)

Output:

```
a(0) = 6
a(2) = 27
```

Code (I have shown more for added difficulty):

```
#+#:###
```

Is a tacit verb.

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77431/12012)

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2, 87 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77453/21487)

```py
n=input()
#####################################################################
print _
```

Output:

```
a(5) = 2
a(10) = 2
a(15) = 1
a(20) = 1
a(25) = 1
```

---

I really should have checked for other sequences before I posted, here's another  one that works ([A014709](http://oeis.org/A014709)):

```py
n=input()
g=lambda n:~n%2*(n/2%2+1)or g(n/2);_=g(n)############################
print _
```

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77453)

Answer (score 1):

## Jolf, 3 bytes [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77484), [A001477](https://oeis.org/A001477)

```
___
```

Examples:

```
0 -> 0

1 -> 1

4 -> 4

9 -> 9
```

Original Code:

```
 "%"
```

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77484)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 18 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77509/41859)

Here's a very short one, at least in terms of PHP. I wonder if it survives <s>this Sunday</s> the next thirty minutes.

**Output**

```
a(0) = -1
a(1) =  0
```

**Source**

```
____$____[1]+_+_0;
#### ####    # #
```

**Notes**

- It's a full program, not a function.
- Reads the input from command line.
- [Does not contain any PHP opening tag](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7098/is-the-php-opening-tag-mandatory-in-byte-count).

---

**Cracked**

The sequence was [A023443](https://oeis.org/A010054):

> a(n) = n - 1

Here's my original source code, which is slightly different to the robber's:

> `echo$argv[1]+-+!0;`

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77509/25180)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://tryj.tk/), 8 bytes ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77535/32014))

`#` marks unrevealed characters

```
(#1-#)#.
```

#### The output:

No, I'm not hiding anything by using a long sample. If the input is **0**, it outputs **0**, if the input is between **1** and **29**, it outputs **1**.

**The outputs for the negative inputs do not match with the actual sequence.**

```
   (#1-#)#.0
0
   (#1-#)#.1
1
   (#1-#)#.2
1
   (#1-#)#.3
1
   (#1-#)#.4
1
   (#1-#)#.5
1
   (#1-#)#.6
1
   (#1-#)#.7
1
   (#1-#)#.8
1
   (#1-#)#.9
1
   (#1-#)#.10
1
   (#1-#)#.11
1
   (#1-#)#.12
1
   (#1-#)#.13
1
   (#1-#)#.14
1
   (#1-#)#.15
1
   (#1-#)#.16
1
   (#1-#)#.17
1
   (#1-#)#.18
1
   (#1-#)#.19
1
   (#1-#)#.20
1
   (#1-#)#.21
1
   (#1-#)#.22
1
   (#1-#)#.23
1
   (#1-#)#.24
1
   (#1-#)#.25
1
   (#1-#)#.26
1
   (#1-#)#.27
1
   (#1-#)#.28
1
   (#1-#)#.29
1
```

Comment: Are you sure it's a function, so `((#1-#)#.)1` also works?

Comment: `((#1-#)#.)1` works.

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77535/32014)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 137 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77551/25180)

This is my final sequence. You should be feeling lucky when trying this one.

**Output**

```
a(3)  =   7
a(7)  =  21
a(23) =  99
```

**Source**

```
for(___range___303_______________________array_merge____)for(__________________________________________)unset________;echo___$argv[1]-1_;
    ###     ###   #######################           ####     ##########################################      ########     ###          #
```

**Notes**

- This sequence starts at `1`.
- The program works up to the last number given bei OEIS, but can easily be adjusted to go to any other value as well.
- It's a full program, not a function.
- Reads the input from command line (obviously).
- [Does not contain any PHP opening tag](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7098/is-the-php-opening-tag-mandatory-in-byte-count).

---

**Cracked**

The wording "*feeling lucky*" and the value `303` in the source were hints to the sequence [A000959](http://oeis.org/A000959):

> *Lucky* numbers

This is my original source, which is slightly different to the robber's:

> `for($n=range(1,303);$j<count($n);++$j,$n=array_merge($n))for($i=($x=$j?$n[$j]:2)-1;isset($n[$i]);$i+=$x)unset($n[$i]);echo$n[$argv[1]-1];`

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77551/25180)

Answer (score 1):

## MATL, 10 bytes, safe!

```
2*##n##qn-
```

Starts at 1, `#` are hidden characters. Sample input/output:

```
a(3)=1
a(8)=2
```

Revealed

> The sequence is the number of primes between n and 2*n. The code used was `2*ZqnGZqn-`. This takes implicit input, doubles it, and finds the number of primes less than that number, pushes the input again and finds the number of primes less than that, and then subtracts the two lengths from each other.

Comment: I was close with `2*_VnGYqn-` (number of decimal figures in `2*input`). But that doesn't seem to be an OEIS sequence

Comment: I'm really surprised you haven't got it! I wan't thinking of anything like that sequence though. The `G` is correct though.....

Answer (score 1):

### Seriously, 14 bytes (Safe)

```
,???D*≈@??D*≈-
```

The `?`s denote the hidden code. This sequence starts at `a(0)`.

Output:

```
a(0) = 1
a(1) = 0
a(3) = 1
```

---

### Solution:

The sequence is:

> [A005614](http://oeis.org/A005614) (the infinite Fibonacci word)

My solution:

> `,;uφD*≈@⌐φD*≈-`

The solution is a straightforward implementation of the formula found on the OEIS page (with an error corrected so that the sequence starts at `n=0` like the page shows, rather than `n=1`).

Comment: I'm assuming your sequence starts at 0.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Given that the first sample output is `a(0)`, that's a safe assumption :)

Comment: No, I mean that either `a(-1)` is undefined or not listed on OEIS.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes You are correct.

Answer (score 1):

### Pyth, 51 bytes, Safe

`#` denote hidden characters:

<s>`K"#"D#d=#:d"#|#"1Rs#?qd"#"####"##"b#W<#K+#1=KhK;@KQ`</s>

```
K"0"Dhd=b:d"0|1"1Rsm?qd"0""01""10"b;W<lK+Q1=KhK;@KQ
```

### Outputs

```
a(0) -> 0
a(1) -> 1
a(2) -> 1
a(4) -> 0
```

This is a fair one.

Thue-morse sequence, A010060.

Answer (score 1):

## C++, 55 bytes (Safe)

This one should be easy...

#### source:

```
bool f(int###########;##r#;r###&1#####+######r######r;}
```

#### Output:

```
f(1)=>0
f(2)=>1
f(3)=>1
f(4)=>0
f(5)=>1
f(6)=>0
f(7)=>1
f(8)=>0
f(9)=>0
f(10)=>0
f(11)=>1
```

### answer

Sequence:

> [A010051](http://oeis.org/A010051) (Characteristic function of primes: 1 if n is prime else 0.)

code:

> bool f(int r){int i=2;for(;r%i&&1-r;i++);return i ==r;}

Comment: I am curious, what is the solution?

Comment: @mIllIbyte my solution is posted

Comment: No obscure language features at all, it's just optimized. Neat!

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 51 bytes ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77616/31516))

Outputs:

```
f 0 -> 0
f 1 -> 1
f 2 -> 1
f 3 -> 0
f 4 -> 0
f 5 -> 3
f 6 -> 5
```

Code:

```
f e=sum[#########$#####(f######=#####e####)#######]
```

This defines a function named `f`, with `#` as the wildcard character.
Shouldn't bee too hard to crack.

Comment: [my guess](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77616/34531)

Comment: @nimi That is exactly identical to my reference answer. I'll edit it here later.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 11 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77603/8478)

Code:

```
->i{######}
```

Output:

```
f(0) = 0
f(1) = 0
f(2) = 0
f(3) = 1
f(4) = 0
f(5) = 0
f(6) = 0
f(7) = 1
f(8) = 0
f(9) = 0
f(10) = 0
f(11) = 1
f(12) = 0
f(13) = 0
f(14) = 0
f(15) = 1
```

And so on, forming A011765. Curious to see if there's more than one way to do this in 6 bytes.

Comment: [Cracked?](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77603/8478)

Comment: What was the intended solution then? :)

Comment: Was being cagey since there might be a way to salvage the trick, but I've added it to the solution thread.

Comment: Here it is in 6 bytes in bc: `!++x%4`

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 123 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77673/38891)

Probably not winning any prizes, but fun nonetheless.

`#` marks a hidden character, it is not used anywhere in the code.

```
def #(#):
 if n<2:
  return n
 else:
  return #(n-1)+#(n-2)

def g(n):
 ######:
  return n
 else:
  return (#(n##)+#(##2))###
```

Sample cases:

```
g(1) -> 1
g(6) -> 8
g(10) -> 7
```

My sequence was [A089911](https://oeis.org/A089911), Fibonacci Numbers mod 12.

Original code:

```
def f(n):
 if n<2:
  return n
 else:
  return f(n-1)+f(n-2)

def g(n):
 if n<2:
  return n
 else:
  return (f(n-1)+f(n-2))%12
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77673/34388).

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, 30 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77420/find-the-program-that-prints-this-integer-sequence-robbers-thread/77663#77663)

`#` marks unrevealed characters.

`n=>M###.##w(n#!#[#+!#[#)-(n##)`

Examples:

```
0 -> 1
1 -> 1
7 -> 43
18 -> 307
```

Original Code:

```
n=>Math.pow(n,!+[]+!+[])-(n-1)
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77663/41859)

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 17 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77420/find-the-program-that-prints-this-integer-sequence-robbers-thread/77690#77690)

```
####a(n):########
```

Test cases:

```
a(1) -> 1
a(2) -> 2
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77420/find-the-program-that-prints-this-integer-sequence-robbers-thread/77690#77690)

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 60 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77691/32686)

```
def a(n):
 if n<#: 
  return #
 else:
  return a(n-#)+a(n-#)
```

Test cases:

```
a(0) -> 1
a(1) -> 1
a(3) -> 2
a(6) -> 6
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77691/32686)

Answer (score 1):

### Seriously, 16 bytes (safe)

```
???"Xi"?≈$?,?R??
```

Examples:

```
a(3) = 1
a(40) = 4
```

This sequence starts at `a(1)`.

---

Sequence:

> http://oeis.org/A001222 (prime divisors of `n` with multiplicity)

Code:

> `ΣM£"Xi"w≈$X,QR£ƒ`

Explanation:

> The neat thing about this code (and the reason why it's difficult to crack) is that the actual divisor-counting part is reversed. Going through the code, everything up until the `,` doesn't actually do anything when executed left-to-right (except for pushing `"Xi"` and then subsequently popping it). `,QR£ƒ` reads in the input (`n`) and executes the code reversed (`Q` pushes the source code, `R` reverses it, and `£ƒ` calls it). Now, the stack contains `n` and the code is `ƒ£RQ,X$≈w"iX"£MΣ`. The first 3 commands (`ƒ£R`) do nothing with an integer on the stack. `Q` pushes the source code (again), `,` does nothing because the input is exhausted, and `X` gets rid of the `Q` result. `$≈` converts the input to a string and back to an int (necessary in the reversed code to prevent unwanted stack items). `w` pushes a list of `[prime, exponent]` pairs for all the prime factors of `n`, and `iX"£MΣ` sums up all of the exponents.

Answer (score 1):

## R 64 bytes

Code

```
##########################
a=function(x)sum(x*3,1,a(x-2):a(x-1))
```

Output

```
a(1) =1
a(2) =1
a(3) =2
a(4) =3
a(5) =5
a(6) =8
a(7) =13
a(8) =21
a(9) =34
a(10)=55
a(11)=89
a(12)=144
a(13)=233
a(14)=377
a(15)=610
a(16)=987
a(17)=1597
a(18)=2584
a(19)=4181
a(20)=6765
```

Simply, Fibonnaci sequence.

Hope it's fun enough.

Answer (score 1):

## Jolf, 3 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77987/31957)

Output:

```
a(0)  =      0
a(4)  =    260
a(10) =  10010
a(23) = 279864
```

Code:

```
###
```

All these features are documented. Yeah, you don't get any parts of the code :P The sequence is off-by-one.

Original:

```
+ΤQ
```

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77987/8478)

Comment: Ah, I thought you might be using `T` because you added it to the docs just before you posted the answer, but I didn't consider combining it with `Q`.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Was it that obvious? XD Nice job, anyhow! Thanks for using Jolf! :D

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78139/34388)

Outputs:

```
a(0) = 1
a(2) = 4
a(10) = 4444
```

Code:

```
____
```

`_` indicates an obfuscated character. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/).

Comment: Easy to find. Easy to implement. Hard to optimize to 4 bytes (stuck at 6 atm). Nice challenge!

Comment: @Emigna Yeah, that's probably going to be the hardest part. I think I know what your current 6 byte solution is, so my tip is that there are 1 byte commands which can replace 2-byte combinations in your code (and there are two of them). Good luck though :)

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78139/47066) I never understood was Â did when I read the spec. Should have just looked at the code. Pretty sure I tried F earlier, but I must have done something wrong. My favorite cop this far :)

Comment: @Emigna Yeah, I might have to make the docs a bit more specific. Great job in cracking though :).

Answer (score 1):

### 05AB1E, 3 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78520/47066)

Output:

```
a(4) = 4
a(6) = 7
```

Code:

```
___
```

_ (underscore) indicates an obfuscated character

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/)

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78520/34388) :)

Comment: @Adnan: Oh come on! Not even 1h :)

Comment: Hahaha, sorry. I always get excited when I see someone else post in 05AB1E :).

Answer (score 1):

### [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78821/47066)

Output:

```
a(3) = 2
a(4) = 7
```

Code:

```
___s_r__
```

_ (underscore) indicates an obfuscated character

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/)

Original Code:

```
ÑDgs`rG^
```

Which is the sequence [A178910](https://oeis.org/A178910) (Binary XOR of divisors of n.)

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78821/34388).

Answer (score 1):

### [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78819/47066)

Output:

```
a(3) = 2
a(4) = 6
```

Code:

```
___
```

_ (underscore) indicates an obfuscated character

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/)

Original Code:

```
D;^
```

Which is the sequence [A003188](https://oeis.org/A003188) (Decimal equivalent of Gray code for n)

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78819/34388). That was a nice puzzle! :)

Answer (score 1):

### LiveCode, 35 bytes, cracked

```
_un_t_on oeis _
    ___u___n__
En__oeis
```

oeis (2)==2

oeis (0)==0

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78673/47066)

Answer (score 1):

### Python, 37 bytes, cracked

```
def a(n):
    return ______!______n____*_
```

a(2)==4
a(4)==16

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78679/47066)

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3, 58 Bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/79060/39462%5D)

`#` marks unrevealed chars.

```
import math;x=int(input());print(int(x/math.####(#)*#**#))
```

If x < 1, it will not work.

```
in    out
1     0
4     457
7     2578097
10    44721359549
13    1760848250285208
16    131994155879539032064
19    16810747184697114703691776
```

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/79060/39462])

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page) (safe)

#### Code

```
??Œ??
```

Each `?` denotes a missing character.

#### Output

```
n a(n)

0    1
1    3
2    9
3   21
4   45
5   93
6  189
7  381
8  765
9 1533
```

This is OEIS entry [A068156](http://oeis.org/A068156).

#### Solution

```
Ḷ¡ŒṘL
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bi2wqHFkuG5mEw&input=&args=OQ)

#### How it works

As noted on the OEIS page, this sequence obeys the recursive formula **a(n + 1) = 2a(n) + 3**, with base cases **a(0) = 1, a(1) = 3**.

The code begins with the integer **n** and applies `Ḷ` (unlength) **n** times, which convert all integers **k** in the previous array into the range **[0, ... k - 1]**. The output after all **n** steps is similar to the set-theoretic definition of **n**.

For **n = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4**, the outputs of `Ḷ¡ŒṘ` (unlength **n** times, then generate Python's string representation) is as follows.

```
0: 0
1: [0]
2: [[], [0]]
3: [[], [[]], [[], [0]]]
4: [[], [[]], [[], [[]]], [[], [[]], [[], [0]]]]
```

If we examine the outputs for **3** and **4** closely, we can note the following pattern.

```
[[], [[]], [[], [0]]]XX[[], [[]], [[], [0]]]X
[[], [[]], [[], [[]]], [[], [[]], [[], [0]]]]
```

The output for **4** consists of two copies of the output for **3** (the actual characters differ, but we're only interested in the length), and three additional characters (**X** marks the spots). Thus, if we take the length with `L`, our program follows the desired recursive formula.

Answer (score 0):

### Python 3, 108 bytes ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77536/51825))

Warning (and hint): my implementation is dreadfully slow...

```
>>> a(0)
0
>>> a(4)
2
>>> a(16)
8
>>> a(20)
42
```

`a(0)` is the first element of the series exactly as defined in OEIS.
`#` is used to hide chars.

```
def a(n):
 ###n####0######n#0
 f=a#######
 return f #f#####a###### f ####a(##f###i#i###a####n##else a#######
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77536/38368)

Answer (score 0):

### Python 3, 50 bytes ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77555/45941))

Another one, because I like this sequence

```python
>>> a(1)
0
>>> a(10)
2303
```

The first number from the sequence is `a(0)`. `#` used to obfuscate characters.

```
from #### import ####
a=lambda n:####(###########)
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77555/45941)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 58 bytes ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77565/30688))

One last series

```python
>>> a(0)
0
>>> a(4)
8
>>> a(5)
17
```

Sequence starts with `a(0)`.

```
a=lambda n:###(###(###)## if ###### else #####(#######)##)
```

Original was different than the cracked, because I can't golf Python :P

```python
a=lambda n:int(3**(n/2)-1 if n%2==0 else 2*3**(n/2-1/2)-1)
```

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77565/30688)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 72 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77595/21487)

```py
print####((#y##########.####c###6#####16#.######)#131963###input()#3###)
```

Outputs:

```
a(1) = 1
a(2) = 2
a(3) = 3
a(4) = 6
a(5) = 9
a(6) = 18
```

`a(1)` is the first element of the sequence. Tested on my personal computer, on [repl.it](http://repl.it) and on [ideone](http://ideone.com) (which have versions 2.7.11, 2.7.2 and 2.7.10 respectively).

---

The sequence is finite, and all terms are listed - it's just [the divisors of 18](http://oeis.org/A018251). However, I overlooked the idea that `#`s could be substituted for newlines...

The original one-liner was:

> `print len((BytesWarning.__doc__*6)[8::16].split()[1319648>>input()*3&7])`

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77595/30688)

Answer (score 0):

### Pyth, 4 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77597/38368)

`#` denote hidden characters:

```
###Q
```

### Output

```
a(1) -> 1
a(2) -> 2
a(3) -> 3
a(10) -> 42
```

Comment: Is this offset at all?

Comment: @muddyfish ... I posted this answer without double-checking. I updated the examples.

Comment: @muddyfish To answer your question, a(0) is the first term of the sequence. I'm not sure if that's what you wanted to know, but at least you know that.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77597/34388).

Answer (score 0):

### Pyth, 29 bytes

```
W##YQ#t^#Z=#h#I#_#=#+Y##;@#tQ
```

Probably not an easy one. Begins at 1.

```
a(1) -> 2
a(2) -> 3
a(3) -> 5
a(4) -> 7
a(5) -> 13
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Molecule](https://github.com/lvivtotoro/molecule/) (v5.5), 25 bytes (UTF-8)

```
"ᘰᜟᘄఄሳÝ̲"C`n
```

No characters are hidden here ;)
An input of `0` is allowed.

Output of 1: `16`
Output of 2: `21`

Comment: You need to hide some characters to make it a valid submission

Comment: The worst thing: It's safe xD

Answer (score 0):

### Python, 42 bytes [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/95339/53745)

```
def f(x):return # if x<#else ######+######
```

Where

```
f(0) -> 0
f(1) -> 1
f(7) -> 13
f(15) -> 610
```

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/95339/12012)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 118 Bytes, Safe

I hope that I'm understand the rules right

```
function f($n){for($a=[],$i=0,$n++;$n!=@@@@@@($a);$i++)if(@@@@@@@)if(@@@@@@@@(@@@@@@@@@@@@@@))$a[]=$i;return end($a);}

echo f(6); # 16
echo f(13);# 32
echo f(0); #2
echo f(1); #4
echo f(54); #128
```

Original code

```
function f($n){
  for($a=[],$i=0,$n++;$n!=sizeof($a);$i++){
      if($t=$i%7)if(in_array($t,array(2,4,6)))$a[]=$i;
  } 
  return end($a);
}
```

generates this [sequence](https://oeis.org/A047292)